# Compare two lists for content

Tags: python, list

I have the given the following two lists:

```
list1 = ['', '', 'void KL15 ein', '{', '}', '', 'void Motor ein', '{', '}', '']
and
list2 = ['KL15 ein', 'Motor ein']
```

Now I want to find out if the a value from the second list `'KL15 ein'` is also in the first list (as a void function).
Do I need to extract the value `'KL15 ein'` from both lists to compare it or is there another way to do it without extracting (via splitting and access the list) the values?
Edit: I noticed that I need variables (can't use 'KL15 ein' as a string), e.g: if the value from list1 is also listed in list 2

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you mean by "*extract*"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is a substring of items in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-substring-of-items-in-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the `set` of void function names from the first list by checking which strings start with `"void "` and then stripping away that bit. Then, you can use a simple list comprehension, `all` expression or `for` loop to check which of the elements in the second list are in that set.

```
lst1 = ['', '', 'void KL15 ein', '{', '}', '', 'void Motor ein', '{', '}', '']
lst2 = ['KL15 ein', 'Motor ein']                                        
void_funs = {s[5:] for s in lst1 if s.startswith("void ")}              
res = [s in void_funs for s in lst2]                                          
# [True, True]
```

Or as a loop with a condition:

```
for s in lst2:
    if s in void_funs:
        # do something
```

Comment: How can I replace the statement `s[5:]` from the line `void_funs = {s[5:] for s in lst1 if s.startswith("void ")} `? As you can see, I edited the question and I can't use the static value (5th of the list).  So I need a variable which contains the values of list2 and compare it with the values from list1 (the ones that startswith("void") should work.

Comment: @Markus `s[5:]` does not mean "the fifth value in the list" but "the substring starting at the fifth character", effectively stripping the `"void "` part off the functions leaving only the name. I don't see why that should not work. If e.g. the number of spaces after `void` can be variable, you might e.g. use `str.split` to split off the "void" part.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know that, thanks. So how could I implement the last line as a if-loop? So if the the values are in the both list: do something?

Comment: Ok with `if [s in void_funs for s in list2` ist works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the issubset() or all() function.

issubset()

```html
if(set(subset_list).issubset(set(large_list))):
    flag = 1
 
# printing result
if (flag):
    print("Yes, list is subset of other.")
else:
    print("No, list is not subset of other.")
```

or all() function

```html
if(all(x in test_list for x in sub_list)):
    flag = 1
 
# printing result
if (flag):
    print("Yes, list is subset of other.")
else:
    print("No, list is not subset of other.")
```