# How to get the desired output with Python Inline Code inside Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I am gathering data using a Netapp module in Ansible. Thereafter using Python Inline Code to apply an operation on that list. Using that Python operation I try to find specific string values in a list. I am using the `command` module to execute Python code inline.

```yaml
---
- hosts: exec-node

  collections:
    - netapp.ontap

  vars_files:
    - secretvars.yaml

  tasks:

    - name: Gather volume info
      tags: vol
      netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
        gather_subset:
          - storage/volumes
        hostname: "nas3.test.com"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        https: true
        validate_certs: false
      register: result

    - debug: var=result['ontap_info']['storage/volumes']['records']
      tags: vol

    - name: create volume list
      tags: vol
      set_fact:
        volume_list: "{{ volume_list|default([]) + [item.name] }}"
      loop: "{{result['ontap_info']['storage/volumes']['records']}}"

    - debug: var=volume_list
      tags: vol

    - name: Python inline code
      command: python3
      args:
        stdin: |
          finallist="{{ volume_list }}"
          finallist1=[]
          for i in finallist:
              if i[0:2]=='yz':
                  finallist1.append(i)
          print(finallist1)
      register: results

    - set_fact:
        x: "{{ results.stdout }}"
```

I am expecting a list (`finallist1`) of my required data like below.

```yaml
['yz16', 'yz18', 'yz11', 'yz13', 'yz14', 'yz17', 'yz15', 'yz32']
```

My raw list (`finallist`) is as below:

```yaml
['yz16', 'yz18', 'yz11', 'yz13', 'yz14', 'yz17', 'yz15', 'yz32', 'test', 'test1']
```

Comment: how about change your logic into list comprehension `finallist1=[i for i in finallist if i.startswith('yz')]`

Comment: You can easily apply that with Jinja filters, is there a reason why you want to use Python for that?

Comment: => `- debug: msg="{{ volume_list | select('match', 'yz') }}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some notes and considerations ... It is not recommended to use Python inline code except there a strong and valid reasons for. Furthermore I like to recommend to name your variables like `list_in` or `inList` and `list_out` or `outList` so that it is easier to understand what they are for.

---

> *My raw list (`finallist`) is as below: `['yz16', 'yz18', 'yz11', 'yz13', 'yz14', 'yz17', 'yz15', 'yz32', 'test', 'test1']`*

According the minimal example in order to debug what is going on internally

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    LIST: ['yz16', 'yz18', 'yz11', 'yz13', 'yz14', 'yz17', 'yz15', 'yz32', 'test', 'test1']

  tasks:

  - name: Python inline code example
    command: /usr/bin/python
    args:
      stdin: |
        list_in = "{{ LIST }}"
        for i in list_in:
          print(i)
        print("Is of type: ", type(list_in))
        print(len(list_in))
    register: results

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ results.stdout}}"
```

which results into the output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    [
    u
    '
    y
    z
    1
    6
    '
    ,
...
    u
    '
    t
    e
    s
    t
    1
    '
    ]
    ('Is of type: ', <type 'str'>)
    91
```

your input is a string not a list.

So, some of the assumptions made are incorrect, `if i[0:2] == 'yz'` can never be `true` and that's why you get an empty list.

At least you would need to cast the type before

```py
        list_in = list_in.split()
        print("Is of type: ", type(list_in))
        print(len(list_in))
```

resulting into an output

```yaml
...
    ('Is of type: ', <type 'list'>)
    10
```

For further debugging you may have a look into

```py
        list_in = list_in.split()
        for i in range(len(list_in)):
          print(list_in[i])
```

or

```py
        list_in = list_in.split()
        list_out = [i for i in list_in if "yz" in i]
        print(list_out)
```

**Similar Python Q&A**

- [How to check if a string is a substring of items in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843158/)

---

Whereby for rapid and fast prototyping, debugging and learning purpose   such kind of coding might be OK, it will probably cause an error prone implementation and non idempotent behavior, will be hard to read and maintain, etc. and shouldn't go into production environments.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline Python. Write a custom filter plugin. It's easy to do, and a great option when your logic is starting to get complex to pull off using the standard playbook syntax.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins

https://netdevops.be/developing-a-custom-ansible-filter-plugin/

Comment: Agree. And for the Custom FIlter Plugin can the above code be used.