# How to determined if a 2 dimensional list contain a value?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list like following

```
mylist = [('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), ('secval1', 'secval2', 'secval3')]
```

how do I see if the list contains 'value2'?

Comment: If you want to see the index of the value within the 2 dimensional list, I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6518412/1799272

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
any('value2' in sublist for sublist in mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am curious if there is a way to get the item that was matched?

Comment: To get the item that contains the value you are looking for, you should use a regular `for` loop and return or break when `'value2'` exists in the list.  If you want to find all matching items, you can use `[sublist for sublist in mylist if 'value2' in sublist]`.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply check all sublists with [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
any('value2' in subl for subl in mylist)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'value2' in (item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist)
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to `any()`, a solution that also supports short-circuiting :

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> mylist = [('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), ('secval1', 'secval2', 'secval3')]
>>> 'value2' in chain(*mylist)
True
```

proof that it short-circuits like `any()`:

```
>>> it=chain(*mylist)
>>> 'value2' in it
True
>>> list(it) #part of iterable still not traversed
['value3', 'secval1', 'secval2', 'secval3']
```

Comment: `any` already does short-circuiting. Test it by creating a class that defines `__nonzero__`, put a `print` statement in there, and use it as the second value in the argument to `any` (when the first is `True`). The `print` statement will not get executed.

Comment: @poorsod I know that, that's why I said `"similar to any()"`. :)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood - thought you were suggesting a replacement for `any` that uses short-circuiting.