# Python: how to ensure method gets a list

Tags: python

I have a method that takes a list of strings. Unfortunately, if the list is only one item long, Python treats this list as a string.

This post has a method for checking whether something is a string, and converting it to a list if it is:
[Python: How to define a function that gets a list of strings OR a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654377/python-how-to-define-a-function-that-gets-a-list-of-strings-or-a-string)

But this seems an incredibly redundant way of getting the item that I passed in as a list to in fact be a list. Is there a better way?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I believe you, python shouldn't behave that way, and it doesn't appear to:

```
>>> def foo(lst):
    print type(lst)

>>> foo(['bar'])
<type 'list'>
```

That post was about a different thing, they wanted the ability to pass a single string or a list of strings and handle both cases as if they were lists of strings. If you're only passing in a list, always treating it as a list should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. As usual, having checked all my code twice before posting, turns out I was calling it in two places, and one of them was a string, not a list. *rolls eyes at self*
But now I know more about how python works, so thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using tuples, not lists, and forgetting to add the comma to the one-item tuple literal(s). `('foo')` is interpreted as simply `'foo'` which would match what you are saying. However, adding a comma to one-item tuple literals will solve this. `('foo',)` returns, well, `('foo',)`.

Answer (score 1):

Python shouldn't do that with a list. A singleton tuple, though, has syntax different from singleton lists:

```
(1) == 1                    # (1) is 1
[1] != 1                    # [1] is a singleton list
(1,) != 1                   # (1,) is a singleton tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. Python does no such transformation to lists of a single element.

Double, Triple check that you are putting the `[]` around the the item you are passing.

If you still can't get it working ***show us the code*!**