# How do I specify the literal generator type in Python?

Tags: python, generator, assert, literals

I need to check if a certain variable is a generator object.
How would I specify the literal generator type in place of the ??? below?

```
def go():
    for i in range(999):
    yield i
la = go()
print repr(type(la))

<type 'generator'>

assert type(la) == ???
```

Comment: It's probably the wrong question to ask. Instead, you can check [if a variable is iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-iterable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you wouldn't. You'd look for attributes with the names of `__iter__` and `next`, both functions.

Comment: That would be signs of iterables and iterators correspondingly, not generators. Solutions by BrenBarn and F.J are more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

Use `types.GeneratorType` (from the `types` module).  You should think, though, about why you're doing this.  It's usually better to avoid explicit type-checking and just try iterating over the object and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
import types
assert isinstance(la, types.GeneratorType)
```