# Automatically use list comprehension/map() recursion if a function is given a list

Tags: python, recursion, list-comprehension

As a Mathematica user, I like functions that automatically "threads over lists" (as the Mathematica people call it - see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html). That means that if a function is given a list instead of a single value, it automatically uses each list entry as an argument and returns a list of the results - e.g.

```
myfunc([1,2,3,4]) -> [myfunc(1),myfunc(2),myfunc(3),myfunc(4)]
```

I implemented this principle in Python like this:

```
def myfunc(x):    
    if isinstance(x,list):
        return [myfunc(thisx) for thisx in x]
    #rest of the function
```

Is this a good way to do it? Can you think of any downsides of this implementation or the strategy overall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is something you're going to do in a lot of functions, you could use a Python decorator. Here's a simple but useful one.

```
def threads_over_lists(fn):
    def wrapped(x, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return [fn(e, *args, **kwargs) for e in x]
        return fn(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

This way, just adding the line `@threads_over_lists` before your function would make it behave this way. For example:

```
@threads_over_lists
def add_1(val):
    return val + 1

print add_1(10)
print add_1([10, 15, 20])

# if there are multiple arguments, threads only over the first element,
# keeping others the same

@threads_over_lists
def add_2_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y

print add_2_numbers(1, 10)
print add_2_numbers([1, 2, 3], 10)
```

You should also consider whether you want this to vectorize only over lists, or also over other iterable objects like tuples and generators. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-a-variable-is-iterable) is a useful StackOverflow question for determining that. Be careful, though- a string is iterable, but you probably won't want your function operating on each character within it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good way to do it.
However, you would have to do it for each function you write.
To avoid that, you could use a [decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) like this one :

```
def threads(fun):
  def wrapper(element_or_list):
    if isinstance(element_or_list, list):
      return [fun(element) for element in element_or_list]
    else:
      return fun(element_or_list)

  return wrapper

@threads
def plusone(e):
  return e + 1

print(plusone(1))
print(plusone([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Look at that- within 30 seconds of each other!

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ahah yeah, I saw that :-)

Comment: One thing I like about mine is that it can vectorize over the first argument while keeping all other arguments constant.

Comment: @DavidRobinson One thing I like about mine is that it's simple for beginners ;-) But yours is indead more useful :-)

Comment: I think both answers are very good. I'm accepting the one which got voted up :)