# Performing operations on each item in a multilevel list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list like:

```
li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
```

How can I apply a function (for example `int`) on all the elements in the list in a Pythonic way?
Example:

```
>>> func_on_all(li, int)
[0, [1, 2], [3, [4, 5], 6, [7], 8], 9]
```

Comment: Should this be 2 seperate questions???

Comment: Yes, it should. Split of the second one please.

Comment: Also: What have you tried? There are no builtin functions for this stuff, but they are both simple exercises if programmed recursively...

Comment: For your `func_on_all`, I'd stick to the function signature of [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). *So `function` first, then the `iterable`(s)*. As it roughly does the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
def to_int(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            yield list(to_int(i))
        else:
            yield int(i)
```

Here is a test run:

```
>>> li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
>>> list(to_int(li))
[0, [1, 2], [3, [4, 5], 6, [7], 8], 9]
```

Note that this only works for nested lists, and can only perform the `int` function. We can make the function more general like so:

```
def deep_map(lst, f=int):  # the parameter `f` is the function
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(i, str):
            yield list(deep_map(i, f))
        else:
            yield f(i)
```

This will allow us to use nested collections other than lists (eg tuples), and we can specify our own function to call on the list.

Comment: `isinstance(i, collections.Iterable)` returns True for strings too.

Comment: I was just going to say that it will be easy to make it work for any func by taking it as an argument. Just one thing, pass `func` to the recursive call.

Comment: I'd name `to_int`, `deep_map(f, iterable)`, to follow the signature of the built-in `map`

Comment: @JanneKarila is right see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1952481/383793) for a test for iterables.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling doing that won't allow for the optional default argument though. Although if you'll be using `deep_map` for a lot of other things than `int`, I guess it would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner the first question:

```
f = lambda obj, el_func: [f(el, el_func) for el in obj] if isinstance(obj, list) else el_func(obj)
f(li, int)
```

Comment: You can also write `def f(obj, el_func): return [ ...` on a single line. `lambda` is for *anonymous* functions.

Comment: @JanneKarila, yeah, I guess that would make more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I like my version :)

```
def recursive_map(func, iterable, kind=list):
    if isinstance(iterable, kind):
        return map(lambda x: recursive_map(func, x), iterable)
    else:
        return func(iterable)
```

Pass into `kind` the class(es) you want the function to use.

Thanks Volatility, forgot about `iter` :)

Comment: `if isinstance(iter, tuple):` ==> `if isinstance(iter, tuple) or isinstance(iter, list):`

Comment: Yeah, would also work. The thing is, you can just change it however you need it.

Comment: @Schoolboy or just `if isinstance(iter, (list, tuple))`. And please don't use `iter` as a variable name - it overwrites the builtin function.

Comment: `class` is a [keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) advices `class_`, but I've seen `klass` a lot too.

Comment: @Volatility You are right about both. I didn't know you could pass a tuple as `isinstance`'s 2nd arg. Also, `class`...

Comment: +1 for staying close to `map` signature. And recursive_map is more explicit than the deep_map, I coined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one :

```
def deploy(l, out) :

    if isinstance(l, list) :
        for i in l :
            deploy(i, out)
    else :
        out.append(l)


def applyFuncOnMultilevelList(li, func) :
    out = []
    deploy(li, out) 
    for i in out :
        func(i)

li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
applyFuncOnMultilevelList(li, print)
```

Comment: No this does not keep the form of the list same.