# Retrieve lyrics from an mp3 file in Python using eyeD3

Tags: python, mp3, mutagen, eyed3

I am currently trying to use Python and its eyeD3 library to extract the lyrics from an mp3 file. The lyrics have been embedded into the mp3 file already (via: MusicBee). I am trying to use eyeD3 to return the lyrics. I can't figure out how to do it. I have searched online extensively and all I've found were tutorials showing how to SET the lyrics. I just want to read them from the file. Here's my current code:

```
track = eyed3.load(path)
tag = track.tag
artist = tag.artist
lyrics = tag.lyrics
```

**artist** returns the artist's name correctly but **lyrics** returns the following:

```
<eyed3.id3.tag.LyricsAccessor object at 0x27402d0>
```

How can I just return the raw text lyrics embedded into an mp3? Is this possible?

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that is a iterator. Try

```
tag.lyrics[0]
```

or

```
for lyric in tag.lyrics:
  print lyric
```

last resort print the objects directory and look for useful functions

```
print dir(tag.lyrics)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for hours. You've helped me so much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you know that it was an iterator? Just so I know for future reference.

Comment: I read the eyed3 id3 source code. I found the documentation lacking, so I went to the truth.

Comment: @DonJuma *lyrics* property is in plural form. So there must be many elements inside that.

Answer (score 3):

this works for me:

```
tag.lyrics[0].text
```

Answer (score 2):

```
u"".join([i.text for i in tag.lyrics])
```

Comment: Can you please add some commentaries for your solution?

Answer (score 0):

DonJuma, Python tells you:

```
<iterator object at hex_location>
```

You can try the following but it fails on strings

```
hasattr(myObj, '__iter__')
```

user:mindu explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable) that you can write a robust function that checks

```
try:
    some_object_iterator = iter(some_object)
except TypeError, te:
    print some_object, 'is not iterable'
```

**BUT!!!**
This is not Pythonic. Python believes in [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python) which basically says, "If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck." See the link for more info.