# Python eyed3 : How to get lyrics of a song?

Tags: python, eyed3

Using eyed3, how can i get or set lyrics of a song ?

I tried this

```
audiofile.tag.lyrics.get()
```

But the method is asking for a parameter, and i have no idea what it should be.

The documentation at [this link](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/api/eyed3.id3.html#eyed3.id3.tag.Tag.lyrics) is unclear (i guess its not complete yet)

Also, if you know about any better library for manipulating mp3 tags, please suggest that too.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182094/retrieve-lyrics-from-an-mp3-file-in-python-using-eyed3).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/_modules/eyed3/id3/tag.html#Tag.lyrics) -

```
@property
def lyrics(self):
    return self._lyrics
```

Seems like lyrics is a property of the class
You can get them directly using the name.

Example -

Getting -

```
print(audiofile.tag.lyrics)
```

Also, `tag.lyrics` is of type  LyricAccessor which is basically an iterator (as its base class is AccessorBase , which supports iteration) . Then for accessing the lyrics you will need to use something like -

```
for lyric in audiofile.tag.lyrics:
    print(lyric)
```

I do not see a setter method in the class, so it may not be possible to set it.