# How to get the lyrics of a song from the song file using python

Tags: python, mp3, mutagen, eyed3

How can I access lyric tag of an mp3 using python modules? Assume mp3 already has lyrics tag filled with track's lyric.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve lyrics from an mp3 file in Python using eyeD3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182094/retrieve-lyrics-from-an-mp3-file-in-python-using-eyed3)

Comment: @PatrickArtner tag.lyrics[0] returns an eyed3 object not a usable string, but using tag.lyrics[0].text solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

theres a module called eyeD3

```
import eyeD3
 tag = eyeD3.Tag()
 tag.link("/some/file.mp3")
 print tag.getArtist()
 ...
```