# Python: Check if an object is a list of strings

Tags: python, types, isinstance

**How to check if an object is a list of strings?** I could only check if an object is string as such:

```
def checktype(obj):
  if isinstance(obj,str):
    print "It's a string"

obj1 = ['foo','bar','bar','black','sheet']
obj2 = [1,2,3,4,5,'bar']
obj3 = 'bar'

for i in [obj1,obj2,obj3]:
  checktype(i)
```

Desired output:

```
It's a list of strings
It's not a list of strings or a single string
It's a single string
```

Comment: For clarity I would rename `checktype` to `is_list_of_string`.

Comment: One edge case to consider: Is `[]` a list of strings, or not?

Comment: nope `[]` wouldn't be a list of string, it's an empty list.

Comment: @2er0: OK. Usually people want to consider `[]` a valid list of 0 anythings, so that's what functions like `all` do. So an answer that just relies on `all` (like Sukrit Kalra's current version) is going to return `True` rather than `False` in that case. The simplest fix is to do `if obj and [rest of check]`.

Comment: `[]` is a valid empty list of strings. I have checked it by validating and it works fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this, I presume? You could do some checks to see if it's a single string.

```
>>> def checktype(obj):
        return bool(obj) and all(isinstance(elem, basestring) for elem in obj)

>>> obj1 = ['foo','bar','bar','black','sheet']
>>> obj2 = [1,2,3,4,5,'bar']
>>> obj3 = 'bar'
>>> for i in [obj1, obj2, obj3] :
        print checktype(i)


True
False
True
```

**Why check for `basestring` instead of `str`?**

You should check for `basestring` instead of `str` since it's a common class from which both the `str` and `unicode` types inherit from. Checking only the `str` leaves out the `unicode` types.

As per [Steven Rumbalski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski) suggestions, if you need to specifically check for a list of strings, you could do.

```
>>> def is_list_of_strings(lst):
        return bool(lst) and not isinstance(lst, basestring) and all(isinstance(elem, basestring) for elem in lst)
        # You could break it down into `if-else` constructs to make it clearer to read.

>>> for i in [obj1, obj2, obj3] :
        print is_list_of_strings(i)


True
False
False
```

**EDIT** - As per [abarnert's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) suggestion, you could also check for a `list` instead of `not isinstance(lst, basestring)`, the code would get rewritten as.

```
>>> def is_list_of_strings(lst):
        return bool(lst) and isinstance(lst, list) and all(isinstance(elem, basestring) for elem in lst)
        # You could break it down into `if-else` constructs to make it clearer to read.

>>> for i in [obj1, obj2, obj3] :
        print is_list_of_strings(i)


True
False
False
```

Moving away from one liners, we could use.

```
>>> def is_list_of_strings(lst):
        if lst and isinstance(lst, list):
            return all(isinstance(elem, basestring) for elem in lst)
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Specification says to test for a *list* of strings, so `checktype('bar')` should return `False`.  Good job using `basestring`.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be better to check `isinstance(lst, list)` than `not isinstance(lst, basestring)`. After all, a dict mapping strings to strings isn't a list of strings any more than a string is… But otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @abarnert : Point taken, and added to the answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't notice the simpler version of @abarnert's suggestion: `return isinstance(lst, list) and all(isinstance(elem, basestring) for elem in lst)`

Comment: I did. I just thought that became too long for a single line. I'll fix that in a second. :)

Comment: I liked that you had split it up.  I thought it was more readable that way.  To each their own.  Either way, it's acceptable to revise your original answer.  That might be clearer than tacking edits to the end.

Comment: Since the OP has now added that he wants `[]` to fail, you need to add a test for `if lst` somewhere.

Comment: @abarnert : Added a `bool(lst)` as the first check. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra: Don't use `bool(lst)`; just use `lst`, as [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) explains.

Comment: @abarnert : That would return an empty list as output for an input of an empty list. Not sure if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @SukritKalra: Ah, I see, you're using `if lst and…` in the multiline statement, but `bool(lst)` just as a shortcut in the one-liner. I guess that unexplained shortcut is the least of the problems with a complex expression that won't even fit into 80 columns, and you already suggested breaking it down for readability and then showed exactly how to do it, so… already great as-is. Never mind.

Comment: From Python 3 on,  you just check for isinstance(lst, str)

Answer (score 19):

To test if all the items in a list are strings, use the [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in and a generator:

```
if all(isinstance(s, str) for s in lis):
```

Note though that, if your list is empty, this will still return `True` since that is technically a list of 0 strings.  However, since you want to consider `[]` as being `False`, you will need to do this:

```
if lis and all(isinstance(s, str) for s in lis):
```

So, your function should be something like this:

```
def checktype(obj):
    # This if statement makes sure input is a list that is not empty
    if obj and isinstance(obj, list): 
        return all(isinstance(s, str) for s in obj)
    else:
        return False
```

This function will only return `True` if its input is a list that is not empty and that is composed entirely of strings.  Anything else (such as `[]`, `['a', 1]`, `('a', 'b')`, etc) will make it return `False`.

Also, using `all` in this way has an added bonus in that it stops checking on the first item it finds that returns `False` (is not a string).  This allows you to work with very large lists quite efficiently.

Comment: Good answer, but change the instance check from `str` to `basestr`.

Comment: … unless, of course, the OP really meant "`list` of `str`" rather than "`list` of strings"… which is possible, but he didn't say that's what he wanted. (@StevenRumbalski explains this pretty well in his answer, so I don't think it's necessary to explain it again here.)

Comment: Well, I went with `str` because, in the OP's post, he was checking if it was type `str`, not `basestring`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Sukrit Kalra's answer, not Steven Rumbalski's. I should have known that an @ and an s would only autocomplete to people who'd commented on this answer, not to everyone on this page…

Comment: @iCodez : Your code would return an empty list as output for an empty list. Your previous `if` check worked perfectly. :)

Comment: This doesn't quite "return `True` if its input is a list that is not empty and that is composed entirely of strings". If the input is an empty list, it returns the input. This may be especially surprising if the input has something added to it while the return value is still being used.

Comment: Oops! Don't know why I did that. I must've been trying to make it like the example if statement I gave above the function.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for Python 3. If for example the variable name is `pins`:

```
if not (pins and isinstance(pins, list) and all(isinstance(pin, str) for pin in pins)):
    raise TypeError('pins must be a list of one or more strings.')
```

It checks for three things:

1. Is is non-empty?
2. Is it a list?
3. Does it contain strings?

---

If you also need to check for uniqueness of the strings, include this fourth check:

```
and (len(pins) == len(set(pins)))
```

Answer (score 3):

As a one liner:

```
assert all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers I've read so far raise exepctions when given a non-list that isn't a string...and isn't iterable either.  That question is addressed in:

[In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable)

Taking the duck-typing approach:

```
def categorize(x):
    result = "not a string or list of strings"
    if isinstance(x, basestring):
        return "It's a single string"
    try:
        if all(isinstance(y, basestring) for y in x):
            return "It's a list of strings"
    except TypeError:
        pass
    return "It's not a list of strings or a single string"

data = [ 5, "xyzzy", list("xyzzy"), ['1', '23', 456]]
for x in data:
    print x, categorize(x)
```

Output:

```
5 It's not a list of strings or a single string
xyzzy It's a single string
['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'y'] It's a list of strings
['1', '23', 456] It's not a list of strings or a single string
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also **convert all elements to str**:
`list(map(str, [1,2,3]))`

**Result:**
`['1', '2', '3']`