# Why doesn't this way of checking a type work?

Tags: python, string, list, types, python-3.10

I am creating a Python object from its string representation:

```py
obj = ast.literal_eval(obj_text)
```

Now, I want to make sure that the object has an appropriate type. In this case, I want it to be a list of strings. This can be done, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495098/python-check-if-an-object-is-a-list-of-strings). Still, I thought that maybe newer (3.10) Python versions will have an easier way to do that, so I tried this instead:

```py
type_ok = (type(obj) == list[str])
```

For some reason, this is always false. So I tried `is` instead:

```py
type_ok = (type(obj) is list[str])
```

But this also always evaluates to `False`. Why is this the case? Isn't `list[str]` the type of, say, `["a", "b", "c"]`? Anyway it seems, like I'll have to use a `for` loop, if this doesn't work.

Comment: `list[str]` is a type hint, not a type. At runtime, there are just heterogeneous lists.

Comment: Note that `isinstance(["a", "b", "c"], list[str])` raises a `TypeError`, rather than returning `True`.

Comment: You need to do something like `isinstance(obj, list) and all(isinstance(i, str) for i in obj)`.

Comment: `assert isinstance(obj, list) and all(isinstance(i, str) for i in obj), f"obj ({obj}) must be a list of strings"
It will create an AssertionError if it is not a list of strings

Comment: _In this case, I want it to be a list of strings_ "list of strings" is not a type.  "list" is a type.  The only way to get what you want is to 1) check that the type of the outer object is `list`, and 2) check that the type of each object inside the list is `str`.

Comment: because `list[str]` is not an actual type. The type is just `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply print the `type` of the types to see why they are not equal.

```
print(type(type(['a', 'b']))) #<class 'type'>
print(type(list[str]))        #<class 'types.GenericAlias'>
```

---

> Anyway it seems, like I'll have to use a for loop, if this doesn't
> work.

There is a way you could do this without an apparent loop, but it is more like a hack. `join` expects an `Iterable` of `str`. If it gets anything other than that, it `raises` an `except` clause. This means you could just test the `list` against `join`.

```
from typing import Any

def is_liststr(obj:Any) -> bool:
    try   : ''.join(obj)
    except: return False
        
    #make sure it is specifically a list
    return isinstance(obj, list)
    
print(is_liststr(['a', 1]))   #False
print(is_liststr(('a', 'b'))) #False
print(is_liststr(['a', 'b'])) #True
```

Comment: why even suggest such a weird, obfuscated way of doing it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ~ because thinking outside of convention is not a sin, it can actually make you much better at thinking, at all. I do not deny your claim. I also do not deny that this will 100% work, without manually looping over the contents. It may even be faster, but I have not tested it so, I am not sure.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ~ may I add: anything we would have done manually in python to check the type, is circumstantially built-in to the `join` function. Using it in this way is allowing `c` to handle the looping and conditions. Albeit strange, in some rights, it's actually brilliant. I'll admit that using `join` in this way has the same spirit as a `side effect`, and is bad practice. That's unfortunate.

Comment: I regret the tone of my original comment. But my primary concern isn't convention, except maybe as an ancillary concern. My primary concern is clarity. with regards to performance, I might also argue that it is unexpected that such a function would create one large string out of the input.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ~ your tone was fine. I haven't received any down votes, which means you didn't give me any. There was arguably respect for my "bonus" possibility, regardless of your agreement with it. I am 100% aware that my solution is strange and hope that automatically claiming it is a hack, puts enough of a warning label on it, for it to be "taken with a grain of salt".

Answer (score -1):

Python is not a strongly typed language. Unlike in C# and other languages, `letters = ["a", "b", "c"]` is not stored as a list of strings, but simply as a generic list. `list[str]` is a type hint in python, not a base type. In order to check whether your variable is a list, instead write `type_ok = (type(obj) == list)`. The only issue with this approach is that it doesn't check whether the list is made of purely strings, but that could be resolved with another check.

Edit:
As chepner noted, `isinstance()` is usually always better. My initial example was showcasing how your current approach was incorrect, but yes, use `isinstance()`.

Comment: No, do not use `type(obj) == list`. Use `isinstance`.

Comment: Python is considered a strongly typed language. You seem to mean *statically* typed. Python is a dynamically typed language (with built-in containers being heterogenous)