# why int object is not iterable while str is into python

Tags: python

As i know we can not iterate int value while we can iterate strings in python.
I want to know exact reason why it is. ?

```
#Example
>>> p = 12
>>> for i in p:
...     print i
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> p = "abctest"
>>> for i in p:
...     print i
... 
a
b
c
t
e
s
t
>>>
```

Edited :
I need exact reason.Please do not say that you can use range , loop.

Comment: Uhm, because a string is a sequence of characters? What do you expect an integer to iterate as? Digits do not form a sequence. Iterating over `12` makes no sense as `1` and `2` have a different *meaning* as integers, while `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` still are the same characters they were in the larger string.

Comment: why downvotes  ?? i am just asking my confusions ..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suppose that it's because anyone who've read at least one book about python would never raise such question, which means that this question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: Actually i was missing exact reason behind it. lot of books are telling int is not iterable and we can iterate strings into python.again i am getting answers like you can use range and other .i know there stuff.

Comment: @aga .. let me know if i wrong ..i am thinking that python is doing indexing for string while for int there is no indexing.that's why we can't iterate int object.

Comment: If you _could_ iterate over an int, what result would you expect to see??

Comment: i am not saying i could iterate .i just want to what is there internally which is not allowing a int to iterate ,while we can iterate sting

Comment: What result would you expect when you could iterate over `16`? And what would you expect for `0x10`?

Comment: @Matthias i want to know why i can't iterate over 16  
??while i can iterate '16' ????

Comment: `16` and `0x10` are same value. So what should the reult be?

Comment: ....The actual answer is "Uh, they decided that ints had no reason to be iterable". See [PEP 276](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0276/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found correct answer.

## Reason:

objects which are having `__iter__` they are iterable.
and we can see

```
>>> dir(16)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
>>>
```

there is no `__iter__` so int is not iterable .
We can check for other types.

```
hasattr(["a"], '__iter__')
True
hasattr(("a",), '__iter__')
True
hasattr(u"12", '__iter__')
False
```

for string there is no **_*iter*_** so how can we say string is Iterable ???
Explanation :
string is  having `__getitem__`

```
>>> dir('1')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>>
```

We can found `__getitem__` so we can say string is iterable.
The iter built-in checks for the `__iter__` method and in  case of strings the `__getitem__` method

Answer (score 2):

A string is a list of characters. An int is not iterable.

Are you thinking about printing the numbers from 0 to 11

```
for i in range(12):
    print(i)
```

or printing the digits

```
for digit in str(12):
    print(digit)
```

Also,

```
>>> list('hello')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> list(12)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Yes. You may convert the int to a string representation of a given base and iterate on that one if you need the int digit by digit.

Answer (score 1):

`Strings` are just lists of characters. `Int` is just integer value. I can't imagine how to iterate over integer value.

If you want to iterate for example from 0 to n you can do

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You are meant to use `range(p)`, for the integers that go from `0` to `p`, now that's iterable, because that is a range of numbers, not a number.

You are precisely meant to do:

```
p = 12
for i in range(p):
    print(i)
```

If you really want to iterate a number you can use this:

```
iterable = '{0:064b}'.format
```

So you can do:

```
p = 12
for i in iterable(p):
    print(i)
```

PD: correct reason why you cannot iterate over an integer is because it is **not** *iterable*. If you are interested on finding which kind of things are *iterable* and why then you should check the question: "[In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable)". Try to run `dir("16")` and `dir(16)`.

Comment: Not sure I get the joke, but the lambda is redundant. You can just use `iterable = '{0:064b}'.format`.

Comment: trylks .. i want to know why i can't iterate int object. i know range and lambda stuff .. please give me correct reason.

Comment: @gnibbler thank you, it's been a while since the last time I programmed (and even more in python).

Comment: @PrashantGaur added a PD with correct reason. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Python all strings are sequences of Unicode characters. There is no such thing as a Python string encoded in UTF-8, or a Python string encoded as CP-1252.
2. `str` is sequence of character so we can iterate while `int` is a unique number. That's why we can't iterate over an `int` object.

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is [PEP-276](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0276/), which was rejected because

> This PEP was rejected on 17 June 2005 with a note to python-dev.
>
> Much of the original need was met by the enumerate() function which was accepted for Python 2.3.
>
> Also, the proposal both allowed and encouraged misuses such as:
>
> >>> for i in 3: print i
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> Likewise, it was not helpful that the proposal would disable the syntax error in statements like:
>
> x, = 1

Answer (score 0):

Rephrased:
"What property of the str class makes it iterable?"

Since you answered your own question (`__getitem__`), I upvoted. (Try `repr(str.__getitem__)`

See also:
[What's the difference between __iter__ and __getitem__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551042/whats-the-difference-between-iter-and-getitem)

https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable