# What's the difference between __iter__ and __getitem__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This happens in Python 2.7.6 and 3.3.3 for me. When I define a class like this

```
class foo:
    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        print(*args)
```

And then try to iterate (and what I thought would call iter) on an instance,

```
bar = foo()
for i in bar:
    print(i)
```

it just counts up by one for the args and prints None forever. Is this intentional as far as the language design is concerned?

Sample output

```
0
None
1
None
2
None
3
None
4
None
5
None
6
None
7
None
8
None
9
None
10
None
```

Comment: The `None` is because you do return anything from `__getitem__`

Comment: see also:  [Stack Overflow: Why does defining `__getitem__` on a class make it iterable in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python)

Comment: @dawg Not correct... It is because of print.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, this is an intended design.  It is documented, well-tested, and relied upon by sequence types such as *str*.

The __getitem__ version is a legacy before Python had modern iterators.  The idea was that any sequence (something that is indexable and has a length) would be automatically iterable using the series s[0], s[1], s[2], ... until *IndexError* or *StopIteration* is raised.

In Python 2.7 for example, strings are iterable because of the __getitem__ method (the *str* type does not have an __iter__ method).

In contrast, the iterator protocol lets any class be iterable without necessarily being indexable (dicts and sets for example).

Here is how to make an iterable class using the legacy style for sequences:

```
>>> class A:
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            if index >= 10:
                raise IndexError
            return index * 111

>>> list(A())
[0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999]
```

Here is how to make an iterable using the __iter__ approach:

```
>>> class B:
        def __iter__(self):
            yield 10
            yield 20
            yield 30


>>> list(B())
[10, 20, 30]
```

For those who are interested in the details, the relevant code is in Objects/iterobject.c:

```
static PyObject *
iter_iternext(PyObject *iterator)
{
    seqiterobject *it;
    PyObject *seq;
    PyObject *result;

    assert(PySeqIter_Check(iterator));
    it = (seqiterobject *)iterator;
    seq = it->it_seq;
    if (seq == NULL)
        return NULL;

    result = PySequence_GetItem(seq, it->it_index);
    if (result != NULL) {
        it->it_index++;
        return result;
    }
    if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_IndexError) ||
        PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_StopIteration))
    {
        PyErr_Clear();
        Py_DECREF(seq);
        it->it_seq = NULL;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and in Objects/abstract.c:

```
int
PySequence_Check(PyObject *s)
{
    if (s == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (PyInstance_Check(s))
        return PyObject_HasAttrString(s, "__getitem__");
    if (PyDict_Check(s))
        return 0;
    return  s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence &&
        s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item != NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I would like to read more about it. Could you please give some docs, where I can read up?

Comment: @thefourtheye Here is a link for the *iter()* function, http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#iter .  Another link in the definition of *iterable*, http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-iterable and a mention that all sequences are iterable in the section on *iterator types*, http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types .  Lastly, there is a write-up in PEP 234, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/ .  Happy reading :-)      .

Answer (score 6):

`__iter__` is the preferred way to iterate through an iterable object. If it is not defined the interpreter will try to simulate its behavior using `__getitem__`. Take a look [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/)

Comment: Agree with @thefourtheye, correct link should be for example [PEP 234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/)

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find it. Edited.

Comment: **Important correction**:  The PEP doesn't not state that \_\_iter\_\_ is *preferred* over \_\_getitem\_\_; rather, it defines both and simply says that \_\_iter\_\_ is *tried first* before falling back to the \_\_getitem\_\_ approach.  The whole point of the PEP was to add iteration support for objects that aren't sequences.  The was no effort to remove the existing sequence support or to deter its use.

Comment: The reason why `__iter__` is tried first is that sometimes could happen that its implementation allows for better performance than the old-style iterator protocol. In this sense it is also the preferred way to do this.

Comment: @Faust It is important to not use the word "preferred" -- that incorrectly suggests that people aren't supposed to use the \_\_getitem\_\_ approach.   You are correct that sometimes \_\_iter\_\_ can have better performance.  That is why I implemented the *listiterator* eventhough it was already iterable using \_\_getitem\_\_.  On the other hand, there was no performance improvement for str/unicode using \_\_iter\_\_.  That is why I didn't add a string iterator.

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you are expecting, you need to have a data element with limited len and return each in sequence:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data=[10,11,12]

    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        print('__getitem__ called with arg {}'.format(arg))
        return self.data[arg]

bar = foo()
for i in bar:
    print('__getitem__ returned {}'.format(i))
```

Prints:

```
__getitem__ called with arg 0
__getitem__ returned 10
__getitem__ called with arg 1
__getitem__ returned 11
__getitem__ called with arg 2
__getitem__ returned 12
__getitem__ called with arg 3
```

Or you can signal the end of the 'sequence' by raising `IndexError` (although `StopIteration` works as well...):

```
class foo:
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        print('__getitem__ called with arg {}'.format(arg))
        if arg>3:
            raise IndexError
        else:    
            return arg

bar = foo()
for i in bar:
    print('__getitem__ returned {}'.format(i))
```

Prints:

```
__getitem__ called with arg 0
__getitem__ returned 0
__getitem__ called with arg 1
__getitem__ returned 1
__getitem__ called with arg 2
__getitem__ returned 2
__getitem__ called with arg 3
__getitem__ returned 3
__getitem__ called with arg 4
```

The for loop is expecting either `IndexError` or `StopIteration` to signal the end of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You asked,

> #### What is the difference between `__getitem__` and `__iter__`?

## What is `__getitem__()`?

Suppose that `arr` is a list. Maybe `arr = ["A", "B", "C"]`

`__getitem__` is a function which is executed when you write:

- `elem = arr[0]`
- `elem = arr[1]`
- `elem = arr[2]`
- etc...

Suppose that we have `lyst = [0, 111, 222, 333]`

Each of the columns in the table below are equivalent in behavior:

```
+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------+
| `elem = lyst[0]`    | `elem = lyst.__getitem__(0)` | `elem = 0`   |
| `elem = lyst[1]`    | `elem = lyst.__getitem__(1)` | `elem = 111` |
| `elem = lyst[2]`    | `elem = lyst.__getitem__(2)` | `elem = 222` |
| `elem = lyst[3]`    | `elem = lyst.__getitem__(3)` | `elem = 333` |
+---------------------+------------------------------+--------------+
```

You can define your own `__getitem__` method in any of the classes you write. An example a custom-made class with a `__getitem__` method is shown below:

```py
from functools import *  
from copy import *

class BaseArray:
   pass

class Array(BaseArray):
    def __init__(self:BaseArray, obj:object):
        if hasattr(obj, `__iter__`):
            it = iter(obj)
            lyst = list(it)
        lyst = self._init_helper(obj)
        self._lyst = lyst  
        self._lvi  = len(lyst) - 1 
        # `lvi` == `last valid index`

    @singledispatchmethod
    def _init_helper(self:BaseArray, obj:object):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @_init_helper.register
    def _init_helper(self:BaseArray, arr:BaseArray):
        self._lyst = deepcopy(arr._lyst) 

    @_init_helper.register
    def _init_helper(self:BaseArray, lyst:list):
        self._lyst = deepcopy(lyst) 

    def __getitem__(self:BaseArray, index:int):
        if index > self._lvi:
            # `lvi` == `last valid index`
            raise IndexError("index is too large")
        return self._lyst

    def __setitem__(self:BaseArray, index:int):
        if index > self._lvi:
            # `lvi`== `last valid index`
            raise IndexError("index is too large")
        self._lyst[index] = index   

    def __iter__(self:BaseArray):  
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

You might or might not care about **C++**, but in **C++** `__getitem__` is known as `operator[]`.

Many different languages have something like python's `__getitem__` method. If you become comfortable with the inner-workings `__getitem__`, it will help you write code in other programming languages as well.

```cpp
# This code is written in C++, not python
int& Array::operator[](int index)
{
    \\ In C++ `this` is like the `self` parameter in python
    if (index >= this->size) {
        throw std::invalid_argument( "index is too large" );
        \\ The `throw` keyword from C++ 
        \\ is known as `raise` in python
        exit(0);
    }
    return this->ptr[index];
}
```

## What is `__iter__()`?

Like `__getitem__`, `__iter__()` is a class method.

`__iter__()` is usually used in `for` loops.

Suppose that `cookie_jar` is a `list` like the following:

```py
["oatmeal 1", "chocolate chip 1", "oatmeal 2"]
```

The following two pieces of code are *syntactically* different, but are *semantically* equivalent:

```py
+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|                              | it = iter(cookie_jar)                   |
| for cookie in cookie_jar:    | while True:                             |
|      print(cookie)           |     try:                                |
|                              |         cookie = next(it)               |
|                              |     except (IndexError, StopIteration): |
|                              |         break                           |
|                              |     print(cookie)                       |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Also, both of the loops shown above do the same thing as the following:

```py
cookie_jar = ["oatmeal 1", "chocolate chip 1", "oatmeal 2"]
it = cookie_jar.__iter__()
while True:
    try:
        cookie = it.__next__()
    except (StopIteration, IndexError):
        break
    print(cookie)
```

Many python container classes, such as `list`, `tuple`, etc... accept any ***iterable*** as input.

That is, you can pass anything as input to `__init__` provided that that thing has an `__iter__` method.

```py
tuppy_the_tuple =  ("A", "B", "C")
lizzy_the_list  =  ["A", "B", "C"]
steve_the_string = "ABC"

chests = [tuppy_the_tuple, lizzy_the_list, steve_the_string]
for chest in chests:
    larry_the_new_list = list(chest)
    print(larry_the_new_list)   


# treasure chests are an example of a "container"
#         __________
#        /\____;;___\
#       | /         /
#       `. ())oo() .
#        |\( ()*^^()^\
#        | |---------|
#        \ |    ))   |
#         \|_________|
```

An example of how to define your own `__iter__` method is shown below:

```py
class BaseCookieJar:
    pass

class CookieJar(BaseCookieJar):
  
    class CookieIterator:

        def __init__(self, cookie_jar:BaseCookieJar):
            self._cookie_jar = cookie_jar
            self._index = 0 
 
        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            if self_index >= len(self._cookie_jar):
                raise StopIteration()
            cookie = self._cookie_jar[self._index]
            self._index += 1
            return cookie 
        # End of Iterator class
    # Resume `CookieJar` class

    def __init__(*ignore_me, **ignore_me_too):  
        self._lyst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    def __iter__(self):
        return type(self).CookieIterator(self)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._lyst)
```

## What happens if you define your own `__getitem__()` method but do not define a `__iter__()` method?

Suppose that you write a class with a `__getitem__()` method, but no `__iter__()` method.

Your class will inherit a default `__iter__()` method. We can emulate the default implementation of `__iter__` with the following analog:

```py
IteratorClass = type(
    iter(
        type(
            "TempClass",
            (object,),
            {
                "__getitem__": lambda *args: None,
            }
        )()
    )
)


class ClassChest:
    """
        Something like this happens when you have
            ___getitem__()
        but you do not have...
            ___iter__()
    """
    # class ChestIterator(IteratorClass):
    # We are not allowed to subclass `iterator`
    #     TypeError: type 'iterator' is not an acceptable base type
    class ChestIterator:
        def __init__(self, chest):
            self._chest = chest
            self._idx = 0
            
        def __next__(self):
            idx = self._idx
            try:
                gold_coin =  self._chest[idx]
            except IndexError:
                raise IndexError from None
            gold_coin =  self._chest.__getitem__(idx)
            self._idx = 1 + self._idx
            return gold_coin
        
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        # End of Iterator
    # Resume Class Chest class
            
    def __iter__(self):
        return type(self).ChestIterator(self)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int):
        if idx > 4:
            raise IndexError
        return idx

instance_chest = ClassChest()

for shiny_object in instance_chest:
    print("mi treazure is == ", shiny_object)


while True:
    iterator = iter(instance_chest)
    iterator = instance_chest.__iter__()
    try:
        shiny_object = next(iterator)
        shiny_object = iterator.__next__()
    except (StopIteration, IndexError):
        break
    print("mi treazure is == ", shiny_object)
```

the console output is:

```
mi treazure is ==  0
mi treazure is ==  1
mi treazure is ==  2
mi treazure is ==  3
mi treazure is ==  4
```

## Some notes about your code

You wrote,

```py
class foo:
    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        print(*args)

bar = foo()
for i in bar:
    print(i)
```

In your code, `None` is printed because you failed to specify the return value of `__getitem__`

Both passages of code in the following table are equivalent:

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|     no `return` statement     |         `return None`         |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| def __getitem__(self, *args): | def __getitem__(self, *args): |
|     print(*args)              |     print(*args)              |
|                               |     return None               |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Let us modify your code a bit:

```py
class Klass:
    def __getitem__(self, idx:int):
        print("Inside __getitem__ `idx` is ", idx)
        return idx

    # WARNING: iter(self).__next__() can cause
    # infinite loops if we do not do one of the following:  
    #     * raise `StopIteration`
    #     * raise `IndexError`

obj = Klass()
for item in obj:
    print("Inside of the `for` loop `item` is:", item)
```

We will have an infinite loop:

```
[...]
Inside of the `for` loop `item` is: 41875
Inside __getitem__ `idx` is  41876
Inside of the `for` loop `item` is: 41876
Inside __getitem__ `idx` is  41877
Inside of the `for` loop `item` is: 41877
Inside __getitem__ `idx` is  41878
Inside of the `for` loop `item` is: 41878
```

We can stop the looping by raising a `StopIteration` exception.

```py
class Klass:
    def __getitem__(self, idx:int):
        if idx > 3: 
            raise StopIteration() 
        print("Inside __getitem__ `idx` is ", idx)
        return idx

obj = Klass()
for item in obj:
    print("Inside of the `for` loop `item` is:", item)
```