# I can't print each element in a queue

Tags: python, queue

I'm a complete beginner for programming. I created the class "queue",added some elements to it and tried to print each element of the queue as following but I couldn't. Please help me!
Thanks in advance!

edited for formatting

```
class queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []


    def isempty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

q=queue()

q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)

for n in q():
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

Comment: , i forgrot to enqueue elements before submission of my question!

Comment: keep in mind that a queue user should have no access to any elements of it except the next one to dequeue.

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello Not necessarily.  Python's own [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) allows indexing as well as enqueue/dequeue operations, although the speed is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through a non-sequence type:

```
for n in q():
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

This is the correct way:

```
for n in q.items:
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create your own class implementation then you you have to define each and every behaviour of that class, the `for` loop is only applicable to `iterables` and to make your object iterable you need to define `__iter__` method inside your class which would be called implicitly whenever you try to iterate over your object.

```
class queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []


    def isempty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.items:
            yield i

q=queue()

q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)

for n in q:
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to define an [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#container.__iter__) method to make your queue iterable, or you need to modify the loop to use your defined methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here `q` is an `instance` of class `queue`. Also `q` is not `callable`.And `items` is the `instance` variable.So you have to use

```
for n in q.items:
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

Comment: This works, but it's probably better to use the object's methods than to directly access its internal state.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the `__getitem__` magic method is possibly the simplest way to make your queue iterable.

```
class queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isempty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.items[i]

q=queue()

q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)

for n in q:
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

Also don't use `for n in q():`. Thats going to try and call your queue object as a function. As `q` is not a function, it fails.

As a consequence of implementing `__getitem__`, you are also able to reference the elements in your queue by index directly on the queue object.

e.g.

```
print q[0]
```

prints

> 3

Comment: I believe `__iter__` is preferable to `__getitem__` as in @ZdaR's answer (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551346/1349673).

Comment: @JamesHirschorn thanks for the info. It's still a worthy alternative answer in the case the user wants to access the queue elements by index., so I'll leave it in place. It's also the only answer giving this method. With the caveats mentioned in your comment, other users should be able to make an informed choice whether its best to use `__iter__` or `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to enqueue something in the queue to print it out!

this code after your class

```
q=queue()
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
q.enqueue(55)

for n in q():
    print "This time, it's: "+ str(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never put anything in the queue.  So it is empty.  Therefore nothing gets printed.  Try adding some objects (call the function q.enqueue) and then perhaps they will print.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when `import Queue` the answer selected above doesn't work.
What really works is that:

```
for i in q.queue:
    print i
```

Comment: She isn't using  the standard libraries `Queue` type. She is defining her own `queue` class.