# for loop in a sequence or in an iterator

Tags: python, for-loop, memory, iterator, sequence

I have 3 object **Item1**, **Item2** and **a custom iterator**. Item2 is same as Item1 but it implements one more function `__iter__()` than Item1, `__iter__()` will return a custom iterator.

```
class Item1():
    def __init__(self, stop):
        self.stop = stop

    def __len__(self):
        return self.stop - 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        if index < self.stop:
            return index + 1
        raise IndexError


class Item2():
    def __init__(self, stop):
        self.stop = stop

    def __len__(self):
        return self.stop - 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        if index < self.stop:
            return index + 1
        raise IndexError

    def __iter__(self):
        iterator = MyIterator(self.stop)
        return iterator


class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, max_num):
        self.max_num = max_num
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index <= self.max_num:
            return self.index
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

When I use for loop to iterate Item1 and Item2, will get same results.
But, I want to know **the usage of memory will be the same** ?
Does the **Item2 have the advantage of iterator**?

```
Item1 = Item1(100000)
item2 = Item2(100000)

for item in item1:
    print(item)

for item in item2:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the memory usage via tracemalloc()

https://medium.com/survata-engineering-blog/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program-49f027e3d1ba

memory usage of your implementation on my machine:

item1: Current memory usage is 0.000379MB; Peak was 0.000593MB

item2: Current memory usage is 0.001218MB; Peak was 0.001478MB

item2 needs more memory

->here is a post about the difference [What's the difference between __iter__ and __getitem__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551042/whats-the-difference-between-iter-and-getitem)