# Iterating over list with for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I saw a code like this:

```
for i in val[0]:                  
    int(i)
    count += 1
```

where val is any defined list. What the for loop iterate over here. Let's suppose val[0] is 5, then will loop go on for 5 times?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: its just a code i saw i meant to say what would the code mean???

Comment: Just a little comment on the thing with `loop through it 5 times`: You can archive that by doing `for i in range(5)`, because `range` returns a list (it doesn't anymore in Python3, because `xrange` became `range`) up to the argument. (Although different things happen if you put more than one argument into the function)

Answer (score 4):

if `val[0]` is `5` you will get an error:

```
>>> for i in 5:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

That code is only valid if `val[0]` is iterable

```
>>> # here val[0] = [1,2,3], which is an iterable list.
>>> val = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], 7]
>>> for i in val[0]:
>>>     print i
1
2
3
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952481/1290264) has a good explanation about what is iterable. Essentially, you can check for iterability by checking for the  `__iter__` method:

```
>>> hasattr([1,2,3,4], '__iter__')
True
>>> hasattr(5, '__iter__')
False
```

Strings can also be used in a `for` loop to iterate over characters, but for some reason they use `__getitem__` instead of `__iter__`:

```
>>> hasattr([u"hello", '__iter__')
False
>>> hasattr([u"hello", '__getitem__')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In python (and anything else I can think of)

```
for i in 5:
    int(i)
    count +=1
```

will throw an error, specifically in Python 2.7 you get

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

are the entries of `val` iterables themselves? So that for example `val[0]=[0,1,2,3,4]`. In this case the above code will work (assuming that you have initialized the variable `count` somewhere).