# Python : reading the output of a function with variable return type

Tags: python, function, return, iterable

I need to use a function from a package that returns either a single object or a numpy array of objects. I would like to read the output of the function in a numpy array, irrespectively of the type of the output.

The reason for this is that I want to be able to iterate over the output. So actually it does not have to be necessarily a numpy array, I just want an iterable object.

For example :

```
import numpy as np

def f(returnArray) :
  if returnArray :
    return np.arange(2)
  else :
    return 1

foo1 = f(True)
foo2 = f(False)

print foo1, foo2
```

output would be

```
[0 1] 1
```

But I want `foo2` to be iterable. As `f` is part of a package I can't modify it of course.

Is there an elegant way to do it (whithout checking whether or not the output is iterable for example) ?

Comment: Perhaps you could return a generator constructed with some `*args`?

Comment: Can't you simply return `[1]` instead of the scalar `1`?

Comment: I wish I could but as stated I can't change anything to `f` as it is part of a package.

Comment: Not sure there's a perfectly clean way to do it. Take a look at this related thread, specifically, the SECOND answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable

Comment: If you send in False as the arg, don't you know for sure that you'll get a single object?  If so, then when it's False you wrap the return value in [].

Comment: You are right, the thing is I do not know beforehand what the function is going to yield.
@Nacho thanks for the link!
I got around the issue by avoiding using the function but I am still interested on some magical solution

Comment: Just a thought, could you instantiate the kind of object that is sometimes returned by itself and then do `if type(return_value) == type(my_instance): ... `