# How to check if object is list of type str - python

Tags: python, list, types

Say I have the following objects.

```
    d = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4"]

    c = 1

    a = ["foo1", 6]
```

I want to check to see if the object is a list of a certain type. If i want to check to see if d is a list and that list contains strings, how would i do that?

d should pass, but c and a should fail the check.

Comment: specifically `list`? Should `("foo", "bar", "baz")` fail as well? Or even a `str`, e.g., `"foobar"`, which is technically iterable as well?

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable) because checking for types is very often not what you want to do in Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 d = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4"]
 print isinstance(d,list) and all(isinstance(x,str) for x in d)
 True
 d = ["foo1", "foo2", 4, "foo4"]
 print isinstance(d,list) and all(isinstance(x,str) for x in d)
 False
```

If `d` is  a `list` and every element in `d` is  a string it will return True.
You can check `int, dict`, etc.. with `isinstance`

Comment: should really use basestring if you want to count unicode as strings also