# Why loop variable is not updated in python

Tags: python

This code is only printing 1 2 4 5..My question is that why p is not updated with the new array at 3rd iteration

```
p = [1, 2, [1, 2, 3], 4, 5]
for each in p:
  if type(each) == int:
    print each
  else:
    p = each
```

Actually to be precise when debugged the code I saw that it actually updating the value of p but `each` variable is not reinitialised again.

Comment: It doesn't change; its reference is just reassigned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of `if type(each) == int:` line. Your third element is a list (`[1, 2, 3]`) and not an int, so it doesn't print anything.

Now what comes to changing the `p` variable: `p` is just a name for an object, not the object itself. If you do `p = each` inside the for loop, it doesn't affect the original object you're looping through, it just changes the name `p` to a *local* name, which points to a different object. As soon as that round of the loop ends, your for loop continues to do its business with the original object you were looping through.

So, notice that `p = each` doesn't change the existing object (the `p` you're looping through), it simply creates a new local name `p` which points to the value of `each`.

---

What you most likely want is something like this:

```
p = [1, 2, [1, 2, 3], 4, 5]
for each in p:
    if isinstance(each, list):
        for x in each:
            print x
    else:
        print each
```

This then again, this isn't recursive, and you'd need a function for that:

```
def print_elements(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            print_elements(element)
        else:
            print element
```

---

If you want to unpack the values into one list to use them for something other than printing, you should use something like this:

```
def recursive_unpack(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            yield from recursive_unpack(element)
        else:
            yield element
```

---

Why I'm using `isinstance()` instead of `type()`: [Differences between isinstance() and type() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python)

Also, if you want this to apply to all iterables (my last example) and not just lists: [In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable)

Comment: Thanks man I completely understood this...And as a matter of fact I already solved it using recursion ..But still thanks..

Comment: @MayukhSarkar If you think you have a better solution, post it here as an answer for everyone to see. If this is your solution, or a better one, please accept my answer as the correct solution :)

Comment: But the without recursion solution will not solve multiple nested list..and the with recursion solution is same as mine

Comment: Yes recursion is the correct way to to do this..but it has some serious memory overhead..all those multiple stack push & pops..Moreover think about a situation where on a limited ARM processor ram, to perform some operation, I want to implement this..All those recursive levels create a hell lot of memory & time overload

Comment: @MayukhSarkar You should accept my solution if it's, there's this little tickmark under the up- and downvote arrows. And what comes to your recursion memory issue, that's a whole different question for you to ask on this site. Your original question was about why isn't the indented list getting printed, and now you're asking about memory optimization. You really should create a new question :)

Comment: I accepted your answer..Sorry I am a new member & hence I didn't know this

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in the else statement, you're basically saying that if the each is not an int (in your case it's a list) then set the list p to the inside list.

I think that what you're trying to do can be accomplished by something like

```
p = [1, 2, [1, 2, 3], 4, 5]
for element in p:
if type(element) == int:
    print element
else:
    for otherElement in element:
        if type(otherElement) == int:
            print otherElement
```

the else statement in this case goes through the inside list and checks the elements it contains (otherElement)