# Class generator without the __iter__() method but object instance works with next()

Tags: python

I am trying to understand code that has a class to create a generator which is later iterated through with the next() built in fiction.

The class in question is this:

```
Class MyGen():
    def __init__(self):
    """ Define some instance attributes"""
        self.foo = 'bar'
        self.some_attribute = 0
    def __next__(self):
        if self.some_attribute < some_condition:
            new_value = self.argument1
            self.some_attribute += 1
            return new_value
```

In a global function, the returned object gets iterated through by the next() built in function. That is...

```
gen = Mygen()
next(gen) # Returns values
```

I don't understand how the class can be a generator without the `__iter__()` method. Is the
 `__iter__()` method necessary to produce a generator from a class? Everywhere I search it seems that `__iter__()` and `__next__()` are used together to create a generator from a class.

I'm fairly new to Python. This code sample was my best attempt at showing where the problem for me is, as the actual code does a lot more and would detract from the question and be too long to put here. I'm not experience enough to know how to shorten it more than this or more info is required.

Comment: `else: raise StopIteration()` if you want to use it as an iterator (otherwise it will yield `None` forever).  Also `def __iter__(self): return self`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32799980/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next(x)` pretty much directly translates to `x.__next__()` in most cases.

So your `__next__` method is called without `gen` being a "real" generator.

The call is valid, it's just a simple method call (makes no assumption nor checks about the object).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Does this mean the __iter__() method is required to make a generator through a class after all? When the x.__next__() method is called with that "fake" generator, will the values be stored in memory or are they created and lost similar to a generator?

Comment: @NickBrady the full iterator protocol is required for e.g. `for _ in x:`; try that and see what happens.

Comment: @NickBrady:  An aside: when you say *generator* I think you mean *iterator*.

Comment: Would it be more Pythonic to create a method that doesn't use the __next__() method as "it's just a simple method call." Thanks again all.

Answer (score 1):

The `__iter__` method on an object should return an iterator for that object. It should be defined for any object which is iterable, and is called by the builtin `iter()` function, or by various statements (e.g. in the initialization step of a `for i in obj:` loop)

An iterator is just something with a `__next__` method that returns the next item for the iterable or raises `StopIteration` when there are no items left. It is called by the builtin `next()` function and is called in various situations (e.g. just before the body of a `for` loop)

A generator is an iterable which is most likely not repeatable so often it is represented as an iterable which is also an iterator. So for most generators they define a `__next__` method to yield the next element, and an `__iter__` method that just returns self.