# function to convert Unix timestamp in bulk in Python

Tags: python, unix, timestamp

Does anyone know how can I convert unix timestamp to readable dates in Python? I've been using this:

```
print(
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    int("1284101485")
).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

but it gets taxing when I have to convert many.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Where are the many timestamps stored? In a file?

Comment: How many is many? What's an acceptable time in your context? What have you tried so far?

Comment: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' can be rewritten as: '%x %X'

Comment: @Paddez No it can't

Comment: @donkopotamus:
`>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1284101485")).strftime('%x %X')
>> '09/10/10 06:51:25'`

UNIX Timestamp -> Readable date.

Comment: @Paddez Exactly ... `%x %X` does not "replace" `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, its output is quite different and since it is utterly ambiguous it is not a readable date ... Day-month ordering differs between locales,  how does a reader know whether that is the 9th of October or the 10th of September?  Is it 1910 or 2010?

Comment: @donkopotamus In that case, you can probably just go with '%c' :)

Comment: @PhilipAdler I've stored them in a csv file

Comment: @Nath I have about 200 timestamps. I haven't tried anything yet, been basically doing it one by one

Comment: Wait is  "taxing" a performance concern?

Comment: @Nath I'm just wondering if there's a function that's able to convert all of them in one go. It's fine if there's none, and totally fine if you don't know either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of the confusion around this question stems from the word "Taxing", people often assume that this means from a computation time perspective but I suspect that you have not yet learned about [for loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

In essence, you need to capture the timestamps in some kind of [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799980/what-exactly-does-iterable-mean-in-python), given that you are using a csv I suggest you look at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) python module. Then you can iterate over the iterable:

```
for timestamp in timestamp_collection:
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            int("1284101485")
            ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    )
```

Comment: This definitely helps! Understand the confusion, my apologies for not being as clear. In my defence:
-I just picked up coding
-English isn't my first language If I understand your code correctly, can timestamp_collection be a list?

#can I change the code to this, to basically reiterate all the values in the timestamp_collection list?

           for timestamp in timestamp_collection:
                   print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                   int("timestamp")
                    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
             )

Comment: @harry yes- timestamp_collection can definitely be a list!

Also, if an answer is helpful please make sure to upvote it, and if it is correct, please mark it correct.

Comment: perfect, already upvoted your answer! certainly most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
print (datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1284101485))
```

Answer (score 0):

If time format isn't really important to you, this will do:

```
>>> from time import ctime as convert
>>> convert(1284101485)
'Fri Sep 10 10:51:25 2010'
```

---

Example of usage:

```
number = 1000

# Here we generate a list with given number of timestamps.
from random import randint

timestamps = []
for i in range(0, number):
    timestamps += [randint(0, 2147483647)]

# Here is actual example of massive conversation.
from time import ctime as convert

for i in range(0, number):
    print(str(i+1)+"\t"+str(timestamps[i])+"\t->\t"+convert(timestamps[i]))
```

Example generates a list with timestamps (ready-to-use data). Next we convert timestamps (in loop) and print them. Code processes (generates, converts and prints) 200 timestamps faster than I can blink, 1k timestamps in less than 0.5 second and 100k in less than 12 seconds. Tested on old PC.

Comment: I've tried this but I can't convert more than 1 timestamp. I have about 200 of them

Comment: @Harry, I am not sure what's wrong. Updated answer with usage example.