# Set difference with iterable list

Tags: python, set

Hi I have problem understanding why is the output as such. I understand set difference between a string and a list (with one item). However, I dont really understand this as there are many items within the list l.

Could anyone explain? :)

It seems like it only take '1','4','9' and set difference it..

```html
>>> l = ['3246', '82576', '2476', '19254', '83254', '92576', '19326', '1547', '325769', '3254698', '1', '254698', '354', '1932', '325', '9325', '1927', '32546', '4', '9']
>>> set('123456789')-set(l)
set(['3', '2', '5', '7', '6', '8'])
```

Comment: `set('123456789')` = `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}` and `'1'`, `'4'`, `'9'` appears in `l`. So if you remove `l` from the other set, you get `{'3', '2', '5', '7', '6', '8'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set` command expects an iterable to convert to a set. Since you only give one string:

```
'123456789'
```

to the first set, it assumes this is it, and breaks this string to the set 1,2...,9 (strings). In l you only have '1','4', and '9' which correspond to these items, and so the difference removes them.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` [expects an iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#sets.Set) to be passed to the constructor.

How does it know that an iterable is passed?

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable) explains

> The iter built-in checks for the **iter** method or in the case of strings the **getitem** method. To check if an object is "list like" and not "string like" then the key is the attributes **getitem** and **iter**:

```
 >>In [9]: hasattr([1,2,3,4], '__iter__')
 >>Out[9]: True
 >>In [11]: hasattr((1,2,3,4), '__iter__')
 >>Out[11]: True
 >>In [12]: hasattr(u"hello", '__iter__')
 >>Out[12]: False
 >>In [14]: hasattr(u"hello", '__getitem__')
 >>Out[14]: True
```

Thus, as a string is broken down to its individual components.
And the further computation is performed.

Also, `Set` does not accept non-iterable values.

```
>>> set(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```