# How To Tell if An Element In A List Is Itself A List? [Python]

Tags: python, list

As an exercise, I'm creating a code which recursively sums the elements of a list, including lists within lists.

Sample list: a = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]

Sample result: 21

My code is as follows:

```
a = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]

def sum(list):
    if len(list[0]) == 1 and len(list) ==1: # case where list is [x]
        return list[0]
    elif len(list[0]) == 1 and len(list) > 1: # case where list is [x, etc]
        return list[0] + sum(list[1:])
    elif len(list[0]) > 1 and len(list == 1): # case where list is [[x,etc]]
        return sum(list[0])
    else:                                     # case where list is [[x, etc], etc]
        return sum(list[0]) + sum(list[1:])

print (sum(a))
```

However, when I try to run this I get the error "object of type 'int' has no length." I was under the impression that list[0] would just have a length of 1 if it's not a list in itself, but obviously, that doesn't work. What should I be doing instead to check whether an element in a list is itself a list?

Comment: Do you want to check only for lists, or also for tuples, sets, dicts, other iterables that can contain numbers, or all iterables such as strings? For a general routine, you probably should recursively "go into" all iterables, sum all numbers, and ignore the rest.

Comment: In this particular case, the only valid elements would be either integer or [integers], so just lists. That being said, if there's a more general way to check, that would probably be better to know for expansion from the exercise.

Comment: To check for an iterable, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable). To check for a number, use `isinstance(x, numbers.Number)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should I be doing instead to check whether an element in a list is itself a list?

```
if isinstance(x, list):
```

**Common Gotchas** You shouldn't name your own variables as `list` because you then overwrite the type `list` and function `list()`

Similarly for your function `sum()`. You wouldn't want to overwrite the `sum()` function that already handles a list of numbers.

---

Or another way would be `hasattr(lst, "__len__")`

```
from numbers import Number

def recur_sum(lst):
  # Return single value immeadiately
  if not lst or lst is None:
    return 0
  if isinstance(lst, Number):
    return lst

  head = None 
  tail = False
  if hasattr(lst, "__len__"):
    _size = len(lst)
    if _size <= 0: # case where list is []
      head = 0
    elif _size >= 1:
      if hasattr(lst[0], "__len__"):  # case where list is [[x,etc]]
        head = recur_sum(lst[0]) 
      else: # case where list is [x]
        head = lst[0] 
    tail = (_size > 1)

  if not tail:
    return head 
  else: 
    return head + recur_sum(lst[1:])
```

Comment: Good catch, I'll rename those as well. Thanks for the assistance, everyone!

Comment: Feel free to check my solution if you want

Answer (score 2):

In short, you may use the **isinstance** function to check if an element is a list or not.

The follwoing code may serve as an example.

```
a = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]
a
Out[3]: 
[1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
isinstance(a,list)
Out[4]: 
True
isinstance(a[0],list)
Out[5]: 
False
isinstance(a[2],list)
Out[6]: 
True
```

Answer (score 0):

For an `item` in the list you may change the if condition to `if type(item) is list:`

```
a = [1,2,[3,4],[5,6]]
for item in a:
    if type(item) is list:
        # do_something_with(item)
        print(item)
```

and the output will look like this:

```
[3,4]
[5,6]
```

Make sure the reserved word `list` is not overwritten as a variable!