# adding class elements to list elements

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.coords = list(args)
    def __add__(self, other):
        temp = []
        for i in range(len(self)):
            tmp.append(self[i] + other[i])
        print(str(tmp))
        return Vector(*tmp)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.coords[key]
```

The goal is to make Vector class objects behave like vectors. I want do the addition operations like this

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
v1 = Vector(3, 2, 1, 0)
result1 = v1 + list
result2 = list + v1
```

and get this results:

```
result1 = Vector(3, 3, 3, 3)
result2 = Vector(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

When i defined the **getitem** method, Vector class started support indexing and `result1` is correct. But `result 2` returns `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Vector") to list`. I ran out of ideas what should I looking for to resolve this.

Comment: You should define `__radd__` as well.

Comment: And have a look at `zip`. `range(len(...))` is always ugly.

Comment: `tmp = [a+b for a,b in zip(self,other)]`, and that will protect from index out of range :)

Comment: Works perfect. Shame on my observation instinct. I was searching in documentation and overlooked the r-methods. Thank You.

Comment: By the way, implementing a `__getitem__` method makes your vectors iterable, (so `for x in self:` loops work) but it's a legacy feature of the language. Consider implementing `__iter__`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable/36407550#36407550) post has more information.