# Python: count overall elements in list of lists

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes a list of numbers and lists, which again can contain numbers and lists, and so on..., and returns the overall amount of numbers that are somewhere in the list.

Example: `[1,[[[0,2],7,3],5,[1,2]],3]` contains 9 numbers in it.

This is my code so far:

```
test=[1,[[[0,2],7,3],5,[1,2]],3]
def flatten(mylist):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        if type(mylist[i]) == int:
            counter += 1
        if type(mylist[i]) == list:
            [item for sublist in mylist[i] for item in sublist]
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

I think I need to recursivley flatten the sublists. But I get the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: In the list comprehension that does not do anything (because you don't assign a name to its value) you are assuming that the elements of `mylist[i]` are lists (`for sublist in mylist[i] ...`). If `mylist[i]` holds one non-iterable element, in your specific case an integer, you will get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def count_ints_in_list(int_list):
    def count(n):
        if isinstance(n, int):  # If it is an integer, add 1 to the count.
            return 1
        elif isinstance(n, str):  # Ignore strings.
            return 0
        elif hasattr(n, '__iter__'):  # If it is iterable, recursively call function.
            return count_ints_in_list(n)
        return 0

    if not hasattr(int_list, '__iter__'):
        return 0

    return sum(count(n) for n in int_list)  # Use a generator to sum the count of all integers.

>>> count_ints_in_list(test)
9

>>> count_ints_in_list('test')
0

# Works with lists, tuples, other non-string iterables.
>>> count_ints_in_list([1, [[(0,2), 7, 3], 5, (1,2)], 3])
9
```

Comment: Note that checking for an `__iter__` method with `hasattr` is error prone. See fact 2 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable/36407550#36407550) answer.

Comment: Noted.  I am aware of those issues but felt they are well beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 6):

a general approach would be to first test an item whether it is iterable. Unfortunately for this, `str` objects are iterable, while in most cases, they should count as one item, so should not be flattened. This method can be used for this test:

```
def is_iterable(item):
    """tests whether `item` is an iterable that is not a string"""
    try:
        iter(item)
        return not isinstance(item, str)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

Then you can use generators and recursion to flatten the iterable:

```
def flatten(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if is_iterable(item):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

list(flatten([1,[[[0,2],7,3],5,[1,2]],3] ))
```

> ```
> [1, 0, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3]
> ```

Then you just need another test, the built-in `sum` and the fact `True` counts as 1 and `False` as 0

```
sum(isinstance(item, int) for item in flatten(mylist))
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the elements you don't need to flatten the list. Simply

```
def count(lst):
    try:
        return sum(count(item) for item in lst)
    except TypeError:
        return 1
```

Note that it is a common approach in python to *assume* the object is iterable, and treat it as such, instead of checking `isinstance(my_list, list)` ("easier to ask for forgiveness than permission").

Comment: did you try `count(('abc', 2))`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: the questions says "numbers and lists". nothing about strings.

Comment: @blue_note,  this nice & shorter to count the numbers +1