# How to clone an iterable and recursively replace specific values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, replace, clone

I'm writing a widget, that allows to specify the arrangement of its parts.

To accomplish this, I'm using the *modular principle*:
**'Building blocks' are used to specify any order.**

These 'blocks' are implemented as an enum values, where each value represents an individual component.

```
import enum

# The 'blocks'
class E(enum.Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3

class Test():
    def __init__(self, arrangement):
        # The passed 'arrangement' is translated into the real arrangement.
        real_arrangement = []

        for a in arrangement:
            if a == E.A:
                real_arrangement.append("a_component")
            elif a == E.B:
                real_arrangement.append("b_component")
            elif a == E.C:
                real_arrangement.append("c_component")

        print(real_arrangement)


# The user can specify an arrangement...
arrangement = (E.A, E.C, E.B)

# ... and pass it to the constructor.
Test(arrangement)

# 'real_arrangement' = ("a_component", "c_component", "b_component")
```

Please note, that **the placeholders are replaced, but the structure is the same.**

---

However, I also like to give some freedom regarding the properties of the elements.
Thus, in addition to the pure enum value, **an iterable can be passed, which contains the enum value and further parameters**.

```
# the elements are iterables themself.
arrangement = ((10, E.A),
               (20, E.C),
               (5, E.B))

# real_arrangement = ((10, "a_component"), (20, "c_component"), (5, "b_component"))
```

Please note, that **the structure remains the same.**

---

#### So I'm basically try to clone an iterable and recursively replace specific values.

Any approach I thought of is quite unreadable.
Is there perhaps already a solution that I can use?

---

*The above code was run with Python 3.5.2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach should work for common (container) classes.

Parameters of the `recursively_replace` function:

- **original** – object on which the recursively replacement should be executed.
- **replacements** – `dict` which holds pairs of the form: `value_to_replace : replacement`.
- **include_original_keys** - `bool` that determines if keys should also be replaced, in the case that `original` is a `dict`. (Default is `False`.)

The function tries to use the same container **classes** as in the original. (**Not** the same container **objects**.)

```
def recursively_replace(original, replacements, include_original_keys=False):
    """Clones an iterable and recursively replaces specific values."""

    # If this function would be called recursively, the parameters 'replacements' and 'include_original_keys'
    # would have to be passed each time. Therefore, a helper function with a reduced parameter list is used
    # for the recursion, which nevertheless can access the said parameters.

    def _recursion_helper(obj):
        #Determine if the object should be replaced. If it is not hashable, the search will throw a TypeError.
        try: 
            if obj in replacements:
                return replacements[obj]
        except TypeError:
            pass

        # An iterable is recursively processed depending on its class.
        if hasattr(obj, "__iter__") and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
            if isinstance(obj, dict):
                contents = {}

                for key, val in obj.items():
                    new_key = _recursion_helper(key) if include_original_keys else key
                    new_val = _recursion_helper(val)

                    contents[new_key] = new_val

            else:
                contents = []

                for element in obj:
                    new_element = _recursion_helper(element)

                    contents.append(new_element)

            # Use the same class as the original.
            return obj.__class__(contents)

        # If it is not replaced and it is not an iterable, return it.
        return obj

    return _recursion_helper(original)


# Demonstration
if __name__ == "__main__":

    import enum

    # Define an enumeration whose values should be replaced later.
    class E(enum.Enum):
        A = 1
        B = 2
        C = 3

    # Map the values to be replaced with their respective replacements.
    dict_with_replacements = {E.A : "a_replacement",
                              E.B : "b_replacement",
                              E.C : "c_replacement"}

    ### example 1 ###
    test = (E.A, E.C, E.B)

    result = recursively_replace(test, dict_with_replacements)

    print(result)       # ('a_component', 'c_component', 'b_component')


    ### example 2 ###
    test = ((10, E.A), (20, E.C), (5, E.B))

    result = recursively_replace(test, dict_with_replacements)

    print(result)       # ((10, 'a_component'), (20, 'c_component'), (5, 'b_component'))


    ### example 3 ###
    test = (E.A, (20, E.C), (5, E.B))

    result = recursively_replace(test, dict_with_replacements)

    print(result)       # ('a_component', (20, 'c_component'), (5, 'b_component'))


    ### example 4 & 5 ###
    test = (E.A, {20:E.C, E.B:5})

    result = recursively_replace(test, dict_with_replacements) 

    print(result)       # ('a_component', {<E.B: 2>: 5, 20: 'c_component'})

    result = recursively_replace(test, dict_with_replacements, True)

    print(result)       # ('a_component', {'b_component': 5, 20: 'c_component'})
```

Answer (score 1):

One option can be to check if an element of `arrangement` [is iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable) and use the appropriate list comprehension depending on the result. So, with some refactoring, you can do this:

```
import enum
import collections

# ...
class Test():
    def __init__(self, arrangement):
        def replace(a):
            if a == E.A:
                return "a_component"
            elif a == E.B:
                return "b_component"
            elif a == E.C:
                return "c_component"
            return a

        real_arrangement = [tuple(replace(e) for e in a) if isinstance(a, collections.Iterable) else replace(a) for a in arrangement]
        print(real_arrangement)

    #...
```

This will make things work for both types of `arrangement` lists (or "mixed" lists) that you posted in your question.

*Without iterable elements:*

```
arrangement = (E.A, E.C, E.B)
Test(arrangement)
# ['a_component', 'c_component', 'b_component']
```

*With all iterable elements:*

```
arrangement = ((10, E.A), (20, E.C), (5, E.B), (1, E.A))
Test(arrangement)
# [(10, 'a_component'), (20, 'c_component'), (5, 'b_component'), (1, 'a_component')]
```

*With some iterable elements:*

```
arrangement = (E.A, (20, E.C), (5, E.B), (1, E.A))
Test(arrangement)
# ['a_component', (20, 'c_component'), (5, 'b_component'), (1, 'a_component')]
```

Comment: Your answer solves perfectly the specific problem. I specified it because I found it a bit more tangible, but I have actually deliberately asked the question a little wider, so that the answer is also useful for users who need to perform such a replacement and have more than one nesting.