# problem: TypeError: 'float' object not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, floating-point

I'm using python 3.2.2 on windows 7.This is part of my code.it reads from an excel file .But when I run the code  it just prints from 0 to 10 and gives" TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable".
Thanks for any help!

```
 pages = [i for i in range(0,19634)]


    for page in  pages:

 x=df.loc[page,["id"]]
 x=x.values
 x=str(x)[2:-2]
 text=df.loc[page,["rev"]]

 def remove_punct(text):
  text=''.join([ch.lower() for ch in text if ch not in exclude])
  tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
  tex = " ".join([wn.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopword])

  removetable = str.maketrans('', '', '1234567890')
  out_list = [s.translate(removetable) for s in tokens1] 
  str_list = list(filter(None,out_list)) 
  line = [i for i in str_list if len(i) > 1]

  return line

 s=df.loc[page,["rev"]].apply(lambda x:remove_punct(x))

 with open('FileNamex.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
     s.to_csv(f, header=False)

 print(s)
```

this is the Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-c71f66bdaca6> in <module>()
     33   return line
     34 
---> 35  s=df.loc[page,["rev"]].apply(lambda x:remove_punct(x))
     36 
     37  with open('FileNamex.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3190             else:
   3191                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3192                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3193 
   3194         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-54-c71f66bdaca6> in <lambda>(x)
     33   return line
     34 
---> 35  s=df.loc[page,["rev"]].apply(lambda x:remove_punct(x))
     36 
     37  with open('FileNamex.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:

<ipython-input-54-c71f66bdaca6> in remove_punct(text)
     22 
     23  def remove_punct(text):
---> 24   text=''.join([ch.lower() for ch in text if ch not in exclude])
     25   tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
     26   tex = " ".join([wn.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopword])

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply a function that iterates `text` (whatever it is) - and ou call it using a `float` value.

`float`s can not be iterated. You can use `text = str(text)` to convert any input to text first - but looking at your code I hesitate to say that would make sense.

You can check if you are handling a float like this:

```
def remove_punct(text):

     if isinstance(text,float): 
         pass   #    do something sensible with floats here
         return #    something sensible

     text=''.join([ch.lower() for ch in text if ch not in exclude])
     tokens = re.split('\W+', text)
     tex = " ".join([wn.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens if word not in stopword])

     removetable = str.maketrans('', '', '1234567890')
     out_list = [s.translate(removetable) for s in tokens1] 
     str_list = list(filter(None,out_list)) 
     line = [i for i in str_list if len(i) > 1]

     return line
```

You can either tackle `float` via `isinstance` or get inspiration from 
[In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable) on how to detect if you provide *any* iterable. You need to handle non-iterables differently.