# Common super class for set, list, SortedSet and other containers in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set `set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, [sorted set](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) `SortedSet(5, 2, 3)`.
I would like to write a function which works similar to all the types above, for example calculate average, or other stuff. I want my function to be safe. In Java there is [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface, common for all standard Java containers.

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet


def is_collection(some_collection):
    return isinstance(some_collection, set) or isinstance(some_collection, list) or isinstance(some_collection, SortedSet)


def calculate_average(some_collection):
    if is_collection(some_collection):
        sum = 0
        size = some_collection.__len__()
        for item in some_collection:
            sum = sum + item

        return sum / size

    return 0
```

Comment: Check for it being iterable ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable

Comment: write your answer, it is acceptable.

And what other options? I would like to learn. Also, I would like to have `__len__()` method defined in such container. I am not sure, if iterable has `__len__()`

Answer (score 2):

In Python **set**, **SortedSet** and **list** are collections that are iterable, so you can just check

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def is_collection(some_collection):
    return isinstance(some_collection, Iterable)
```

That should work for all of your collections, as all of them have `__len__()` method that can be used.