# Is series data structure in python an iterable?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I confirm that a pandas `Series` data structure in Python is an iterable?

Comment: What happens when you try and iterate through it?

Comment: `for i in mySer: print(i)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable)

Comment: @Evan , thanks , it does answer the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a try/except block:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['One'])  
try: 
     iter(series) 
     print('your object is iterable') 
except TypeError: 
     print(series, ' is not iterable') 

# your object is iterable
```

or

```
series = 1  
try: 
     iter(series) 
     print('your object is iterable') 
except TypeError: 
     print(series, ' is not iterable') 

# 1 is not iterable
```