# Ensure variable is a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I often find myself in a situation where I have a variable that may or may not be a list of items that I want to iterate over. If it's not a list I'll make a list out of it so I can still iterate over it. That way I don't have to write the code inside the loop twice.

```
def dispatch(stuff):
   if type(stuff) is list:
       stuff = [stuff]

   for item in stuff:
      # this could be several lines of code
      do_something_with(item)
```

What I don't like about this is (1) the two extra lines (2) the type checking which is generally discouraged (3) besides I really should be checking if stuff is an iterable because it could as well be a tuple, but then it gets [even more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1952464/839963). The point is, any robust solution I can think of involves an unpleasant amount of boilerplate code.

You *cannot* ensure stuff is a list by writing `for item in [stuff]` because it will make a nested list if stuff is already a list, and not iterate over the items in stuff. And you can't do `for item in list(stuff)` either because the constructor of list throws an error if stuff is not an iterable.

So the question I'd like to ask: is there anything obvious I've missed to the effect of `ensurelist(stuff)`, and if not, can you think of a reason why such functionality is not made easily accessible by the language?

Edit:
In particular, I wonder why list(x) doesn't allow x to be non-iterable, simply returning a list with x as a single item.

Comment: `"You cannot ensure stuff is a list by writing for item in [stuff] because it will make a nested list if stuff is already a list"` which is exactly what your current  `if` condition is doing as well. Did you mean `if not isinstance(stuff, list)` ?

Comment: Why do you consider `if not isinstance(e, Iterable):` "complicated" or "boilerplate" ? The only caveat I see is that you need to remember that `str` is also `Iterable`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp -`try:` iterating and catch the error if it's not iterable.

Comment: Type checking is indeed generally discouraged, but having an `ensurelist` function wouldn’t really *not* be type checking. Instead, I’d recommend looking at why you find yourself in this situation and whether there’s a way to have a better-typed API. For example, the caller taking on the responsibility of providing the right type with `dispatch([stuff])`. (Equivalently, `def dispatch(*stuff):`, putting responsibility on callers that would like to pass iterables.)

Comment: @Ry- this only shifts the problem to the calling code. if `stuff` is already a list then `dispatch` is called with a nested list

Comment: @DeepSpace As explained in the question, I'd prefer not having to wrote two extra lines of code for this. Testing for ```Iterable``` is a good idea, but it's requires you to import from ```collections.abc``` which introduces another extra line. It just seems like a lot of code for something so trivial that should be doable with zero extra lines.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Yes, I’m saying the caller should know what type it has.

Comment: @Glemi How many lines your entire code base has? 100? 300? are you **really** that worried about 2-3 extra lines? sounds like an extreme micro/premature optimization

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote? No research effort? Unclear? Not useful?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I do think doing this is never a good idea. (DeepSpace already mentioned `str`, which is a common practical issue even for code whose cleanliness you don’t really care about.)

Comment: Sure @DeepSpace it could be considered micro-optimization, but I still thought it was an interesting enough question to ask. Btw @Ry-♦ I *really* like the ```def dispatch(*stuff)``` suggestion, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example of the classes defined in the `io` module, which provide separate `write` and `writelines` methods for writing a single line and writing a list of lines. Provide separate functions that do different things. (One can even use the other.)

```
def dispatch(stuff):
   do_something_with(item)


def dispatch_all(stuff):
    for item in stuff:
        dispatch(item)
```

The caller will have an easier time deciding whether `dispatch` or `dispatch_all` is the correct function to use than your do-it-all function will have deciding whether it needs to iterate over its argument or not.