# How do we know if an item can be iterated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read some very old answers on this(10 years), and they say that in python 2.x this quality of iteration was just presumed.

But what about modern python like 3.9 ?  Can I assume an item and object can be iterated ?

Abi

Comment: probably not the best way, but any object with an `__iter__` method is a good candidate for iteration

Comment: Asked and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer below code and pass your object to find whether it is iterable or not.

```py
def isiterable(obj):
  try:
     iter(obj)
     return True
  except TypeError:
     return False
```

Good Day!

Answer (score 0):

The shining new `typing` module is exactly for that. It contains all types.

```
from typing import Iterable
isinstance([], Iterable) # True
isinstance(None, Iterable) # False
```

Comment: ``typing`` does not exist for runtime checking. The older ``collections.abc`` exists for this, e.g. ``collections.abc.Iterable``.

Comment: Based on [collections.abs.Iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) docs, we shouldn't use `isinstance` for iterables, as old style iterable are not identified by it. It seems that @Prince answer is the recommended way.