# count the sum of the nested list which contains strings and ints in python

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I know how to get the sum of a nested list that only contains numbers but how do i get the sum of a nested list that contains both strings and numbers?

```
def sum_all_numbers(seq):
    if not seq:
        return 0
    elif isinstance(seq[0], str):
        seq.remove(seq[0])
    elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return sum_all_numbers(seq[0]) + sum_all_numbers(seq[1:])
    else:
        return seq[0] + sum_all_numbers(seq[1:])
```

I wanted to use double recursion to solve this problem but i don't manage to get the isinstance part right.

```
sum_all_numbers(["a", "b", ["c", 3, 4, [5, "d"], 10], 9])
```

is the input

Comment: Note that when you do `seq.remove(seq[0])`, you're actually modifying `seq` and deleting an element!! This is not what your function is supposed to do; it's only supposed to sum the numbers without damaging the list. Other languages have a `const` keyword to guarantee that a function won't damage its arguments; python doesn't, so you have to be extra careful.

Answer (score 0):

you can flatten all the list to a single list and then traverse and filter the list reuslt  or while traversing the list filter the values.

using the second method adding code

```
# your code goes here
def get_sum(array: list):
    sum_ = 0
    for i in array:
        if type(i)==int:
            sum_+= i
        elif type(i) in [list, tuple]:
            sum_+= get_sum(i)
    return sum_


result = get_sum(["a", "b", ["c", 3, 4,(1,2,['a', 'b', [1,2,0]],'a',33), [5, "d"], 10], 9])
print(result)
# output 70
```

Comment: Why did you replace the OP's `isinstance()` with `type() ==`? See also [What are the differences between `type` and `isinstance`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance/1549854)

Comment: in this case `type` is better than `isinstance` in this case

Comment: You make it sound like it's just your personal taste ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using:

- `try/except` to try adding numbers;
- `isinstance(x, (str, bytes))` to test if `x` is a string.

This way, you can add any numbers, not just `int`.

```py
def sum_all_numbers(seq):
    result = 0
    for x in seq:
        try:
            result += x
        except TypeError:
            if not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
                result += sum_all_numbers(x)
    return result

print( sum_all_numbers(["a", "b", ["c", 3, 4, [5, "d"], 10], 9]) )
# 31
```

Note that this version will fail if the nested structure contains something that is not a number, a string, or an iterable:

```py
sum_all_numbers([None, 3, 4])
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

To fix it, we can use a new `try/except` with `iter`:

```py
def sum_all_numbers(seq):
    result = 0
    for x in seq:
        try:
            result += x
        except TypeError:
            if not isinstance(x, (str, bytes)):
                try:
                    subseq = iter(x)
                    result += sum_all_numbers(subseq)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
    return result

print( sum_all_numbers(["a", "b", ["c", 3, 4, [None, 12.0], [5, "d"], 10], 9]) )
# 43.0
```

I suggest reading [the python sourcecode of more_itertools.collapse](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#collapse), for more ideas and error-handling to include in this function.

Comment: try and exxcept is a costly operation and to use them twice is bad practice. to check any type of object you can check whether that ojbect is iterable or not ie `object.__iter__` and based on output you can make/take a decision no need to use these try and except heavy operation

Comment: @sahasrara62 I disagree with your comment. Some objects are iterable, yet do not implement the `.__iter__` method that you mention. See [In python, how do I determine if an object is iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952464/in-python-how-do-i-determine-if-an-object-is-iterable) for a longer discussion on that matter.