# Type annotation for non iterables

Tags: python, annotations

I want to write an annotation for variables that are not iterables.

```
def f(x: NonIterable):
    if not isinstance(x, Iterable):
        pass
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

As you can see in the function the definition of a `NonIterable` is clear, but I am struggling to turn that into a type annotation.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70618057/is-it-possible-to-write-a-negative-python-type-annotation

Comment: Even if there were such an annotation, it would be extremely difficult to actually pass anything to `f` in a statically-valid way. Even an `int` could be an `Iterable`, if it's an instance of some weird `int` subclass.

Comment: Thanks @TomerAriel, the question is the same as mine and I see I'm not the only one that thought about negative type annotations. Unfortunately the answer seems to be that negative type annotations are not possible in Python!