# how to create a function "is_float" which work either with single value and an itterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function "is_float" which can test if a value is a float or an iterrable which contains only floating point number.

for just one value, I did this (it works fine to me):

```
def is_float(value: Any) -> bool:
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Cannot convert "{value}" to a floating point number.')
        return False
```

But I also tried this with an itterable :

```
def is_float(value: Iterable[Any]) -> bool:
    try:
        for item in value:
            float(item)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Cannot convert "{item}" to a floating point number.')
        return False
```

And of course... it is not working if value is not an "iterable" but just an int or a string for exemple.

Is there a simple way to do that otherwise than adding an if statement to check if the iterable contain only one value ?

Thanks !

Comment: A string is _also_ an iterable, so I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Comment: You could check the type of the object directly, and if it's not string/int/float, then you could just assume it's an iterable.

Comment: Plus it would be good to bear in mind that functions such as float() raise TypeErrors  when a not supported type is passed to them.

Comment: Don't do this. Make two seperate functions (one using the other...)

Comment: I'm sure you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1952464/5987