# Performance comparison of using `in` vs try except in python

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a dictionary in some code which maps a key to a word, the key is the result of an `md5` hash.  I have code that essentially wants to get the `key` for a `word`, and when it doesn't already exist, add it to the dictionary

Here was my first implementation:

```
key = int(hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest(), 16)
if key in self.id_to_word.keys():
    assert word == self.id_to_word[key]
else:
    self.id_to_word[key] = word
return key
```

After profiling my code I found this to be EXTREMELY slow.  So then I tried this, which is functionally equivalent

```
key = int(hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest(), 16)

try:
    assert word == self.id_to_word[key]
    return key
except KeyError:
    self.id_to_word[key] = word
```

This turned out to be incredibly faster.  While I'm certainly happy about the performance improvement, I was wondering if someone could explain to me why.  Is it bad practice to check for something in a `keys()` function from a dictionary like that?  Is it generating copies of that every time (wasting a lot of computation)?

Comment: can just do `key in some_dict`, don't have to use `.keys()`

Comment: Could you add the actual time results?

Comment: .keys() creates a list of all the keys, and the `in` statement searches all those keys, an O(N) operation. `key in dict` is O(1) operation

Comment: This discussion doesn't work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1835756/349420 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id_to_word.keys()` creates a new list, which is linearly searched, which is much slower than a hash lookup. Remove the `.keys()`.

The fastest way would be:

```
key = int(hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest(), 16)
assert word == self.id_to_word.setdefault(key, word)
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that `assert` should not be used in production code.  `python -O` (the optimize flag) will remove an assert from code.  At that time, your code breaks.

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected (in python2). The `keys()` method returns a **list** of keys. So using the `in` operator on the list takes linear time.

Trying to access the item is constant time, which is much faster.

Note: you can simply use `key in dictionary` instead of the `try: ...except:`.

---

Note that dictionaries have a [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method that already does what you want. Moreover if you do that operation a lot of time you should consider using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a plain dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`key in some_dict` is much faster than `key in some_dict.keys()`

Dict Lookup `key in some_dict` is `O(1)` complexity so its very fast

that said its still (very marginally)slower in the case where the key is in the dict than just `try/except`

the real answer is there is no real measurable difference between these 2 methods and do whatever feels right to you

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comments above:

```
In [4]: d = {k:k for k in xrange(1000)}
In [5]: %timeit 50 in d
10000000 loops, best of 3: 68.6 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit 50 in d.keys()
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.35 µs per loop
```

as you can see, using d.keys() is about 100 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `setdefault()` solves your problem without an `if` or `try` block.
But "Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission" [EAFP] and duck-typing is a common idiom in Python, compared to the more defensive "Look Before You Leap" [LBYL] idiom common in other languages, e.g. Java, C++.

Jeff Knuth has an interesting blog post on it [Write Clean Python: Use Exceptions](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/)