# How to find duplicates of list of arbitrary sized lists in < n^2 time in python?

Tags: python

How do I find duplicates in the list of lists in < n^2 in python?
I cannot use a dictionary to do it in linear time as if I did with all standard types. 
I can only think of the following solution:

```
arr = [[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2], [5,6], [8], [8]]
unique_arr = []
dups = []

for item in arr:
    for item2 in unique_arr:
         if (item == item2).all():
            dups.append(item)
            continue
    unique_arr.append(item)
```

expected result for `dups` is `[[1,2], [8]]`

Thanks

Comment: *I can only think of the following solution:* - why?

Comment: You could convert your lists to something hashable since they just contain integers.  Tuples are hashable.

Comment: How about sorting the list?

Comment: @Tyger is it? in that question, all answers are mostly specific to the case where you have this format [value, counter]. I have a list of arbitrary sized lists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution with `collections.Counter`:

```
arr = [[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2], [5,6], [8], [8]]

from collections import Counter

print([[*i] for i,c in Counter(map(tuple, arr)).items() if c > 1])
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2], [8]]
```

OR:

Version with `itertools.groupby` and `sorted`:

```
from itertools import groupby
print([v for v, g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=len)) if any(i > 0 for i, _ in enumerate(g))])
```

Prints:

```
[[8], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: and what complexity is that?

Comment: `collections.Counter` is O(n)

Comment: @YohanRoth As @user3483203 staded, version with `Counter` is O(n). Version with groupby/sorted is O(nlogn) for sorted and O(n) for groupby

Comment: Worth noting that neither of these options preserves order, if that matters to you

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need to iterate through the internal lists... You can simply iterate the outer list.

```
arr = [[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2], [5,6], [8], [8]]
unique_arr = []
dups = []

for item in arr:
    if item not in unique_arr:
        unique_arr.append(item)
    else:
        unique_arr.append(item)
```

Comment: I think "not in" functionality is implemented as a loop too. So it is the same stuff

Comment: This still has the same complexity, just way faster because the list comparison is probably in C instead of python, and using an algorithm that is correct

Comment: @Cireo oh I see, sure. But the actual time complexity is the same, while I am looking for smth < n^2

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution for you:

```py
arr = [[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2], [5,6], [8], [8]]

dic = {}
dups = []

for ele in arr:
    try:
        if dic[str(ele)] is 1:
            dups.append(ele)
    except:
        dic[str(ele)] = 1


print(dups)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [8]]
```

Comment: popping from front of the list is O(n) so this would be O(n^2)?

Comment: its still O(n^2) since `if popped in arr:` is O(n)

Comment: @Tyger Now What about the complexity?

Comment: @Tyger accessing or inserting the data to a dictionary has the complexity O(1).

Comment: I like your persistence you might wanna check this [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python)

Comment: Okay I agree with you timing of accepted code is 24.07005401099923 and timing of my code is 26.193061662999753.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't use lists as dictionary keys, you can use tuples.

```
arr = [[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2], [5,6], [8], [8]]
dups = []
found = set()
for item in arr:
    tup = tuple(item)
    if tup in found:
        dups.append(list(tup))
    found.add(tup)
print(dups)
```