# How to fix 'KeyError' error in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning how to use BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to read the weather from Google. I'm using this [URL](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSfZJRq-EqvQ7rSC0oFZW-FiL-S-Q%3A1571602469929&source=hp&ei=JcCsXb-ANoK4kwWgtK_4DQ&q=what%27s%20the%20weather%20today&oq=whats%20the%20weather%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i10i70i256j0i10j0j0i10l3j0l3j0i10.663.2962..4144...0.0..0.82.1251.19......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..35i362i39j35i39j0i131.AWESAgn5njA).

I'm getting a 'KeyError: "id"' error on the line:

```
if span.attrs["id"] == "wob_tm":
```

What does this mean and how can I solve this problem?

I got the same error specifying a different attribute, "class", so I thought it might have just been a problem with the term "class" but I'm still recieving the error no matter what I use

```
# Creates a list containing all appearences of the 'span' tag
# The weather value is located within a span tag
spans = soup.find_all("span")

for span in spans:

    if span.attrs["id"] == "wob_tm":

        print(span.content)
```

I expect the output to be the integer value of the weather but when I run the code I just get:
"KeyError: 'id'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the rest of the answers are legit, none will work in that case because the content of temperature is loaded probably using `javascript` so the `spans`  you're looking won't be found. Instead you can use `selenium` that works fo sure. i.e.:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSfZJRq-EqvQ7rSC0oFZW-FiL-S-Q%3A1571602469929&source=hp&ei=JcCsXb-ANoK4kwWgtK_4DQ&q=what%27s+the+weather+today&oq=whats+the+weather+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i10i70i256j0i10j0j0i10l3j0l3j0i10.663.2962..4144...0.0..0.82.1251.19......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..35i362i39j35i39j0i131.AWESAgn5njA")

temp = driver.find_element_by_id('wob_tm').text
print(temp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Some `span` tags don't have that attribute at all, so they give you the error when you try and access that. You could just refine your search:

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', {'id': 'wob_tm'})
```

This would find only objects that match. You can then just print them all:

```
for span in spans:
    print(span.content)
```

Comment: Alternatively using css selectors: `span = soup.select_one('span#wob_tm')`... it assumes the id is unique, but then things get messy if IDs are duplicated anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The problem that there is no 'id' key in the dictionary 'attrs'. The code below will handle this case.

```
spans = soup.find_all("span")
for span in spans:
    if span.attrs.get("id") == "wob_tm":
        print(span.content)
    else:
        print('not wob_tm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Weather data is **not** rendered with JavaScript as [Kostas Charitidis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504409/15164646) mentioned.

You don't need to specify `<span>` element, and more over you don't need to use `find_all()`/`findAll()`/`select()` since you're looking just for **one** element that doesn't repeat anywhere else. Use `select_one()` instead:

```py
soup.select_one('#wob_tm').text
# prints temperature
```

You can also use `try/except` if you want to return `None`:

```py
try:
  temperature = soup.select_one('#wob_tm').text
except: temperature = None
```

[An `if` statement always costs you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835844/15164646), it's nearly free to set up a `try/except` block. But when an `Exception` actually occurs, the cost is much higher.

The next problem that might cause that error would be no `user-agent` specified so Google would block your request eventually thus you'll receive a completely different HTML. I already answered about [what is `user-agent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68979968/15164646).

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Weather-Answer-Box-bs4-python-serpapi#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "london weather",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

weather_condition = soup.select_one('#wob_dc').text
tempature = soup.select_one('#wob_tm').text
precipitation = soup.select_one('#wob_pp').text
humidity = soup.select_one('#wob_hm').text
wind = soup.select_one('#wob_ws').text
current_time = soup.select_one('#wob_dts').text

print(f'Weather condition: {weather_condition}\n'
      f'Temperature: {tempature}°F\n'
      f'Precipitation: {precipitation}\n'
      f'Humidity: {humidity}\n'
      f'Wind speed: {wind}\n'
      f'Current time: {current_time}\n')

----
'''
Weather condition: Mostly cloudy
Temperature: 60°F
Precipitation: 3%
Humidity: 77%
Wind speed: 3 mph
Current time: Friday 7:00 AM
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this by using the [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out how to extract elements since it's already done for the end-user and no need to maintain a parser over time. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and get what you were looking for.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "london weather",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

loc = results['answer_box']['location']
weather_date = results['answer_box']['date']
weather = results['answer_box']['weather']
temp = results['answer_box']['temperature']
precipitation = results['answer_box']['precipitation']
humidity = results['answer_box']['humidity']
wind = results['answer_box']['wind']

print(f'{loc}\n{weather_date}\n{weather}\n{temp}°F\n{precipitation}\n{humidity}\n{wind}\n')

-------
'''
District 3
Friday
Mostly sunny
80°F
0%
52%
5 mph
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.