# Removal of tuple of length 2 from set, regardless of the order of the values

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have a set of tuples of length 2. Tuples in set could be in format `(x,y)` or reversed `(y,x)`.
It's guaranteed that there exist one tuple `(x,y)` or `(y,x)` in the set, but I can't know in advance in what order.

I need to remove either `(x,y)` or `(y,x)` from the set, without knowing which it is.

I tried it like this:

```
def flexRemove(S, tup):
    try:
        S.remove(tup)
    except:
        S.remove(tuple([tup[1], tup[0]]))

S = {(6, 1), (2, 4), (3, 8), (7, 5)}
flexRemove(S, (4, 2))
```

The above example removes `(4,2)` or `(2,4)` from the set, as desired.

Is there more elegant or more pythonic way to achieve this (without invoking the Exception)?

Comment: Python style is [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp). Using Exception is pythonic. You should not catch all Exception though, only the one that interest you. (`KeyError` in that case)

Comment: The only thing I would mention is that you avoid try/except syntax when not absolutely necessary. In your case you can replace `try` with `if tup in S` and `except` with `else`. The rest is pythonic enough.

Comment: @kuco23 I disagree. Exception are more pythonic than [Look before you leap](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-lbyl)

Comment: @Lescurel I see the issue being with multithreading. Though in this case I would prefer readability. Anyway, OP should at least specify the exception type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `if ... else` statement instead of the `try ... except` block.
Quoting this answer [Using try vs if in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835756/using-try-vs-if-in-python/1835844)

> So, whereas an if statement always costs you, it's nearly free to set
> up a try/except block. But when an Exception actually occurs, the cost
> is much higher.

Therefore if your code raises an exception too often, then the `try...except` syntax is less performant. Also I find the syntax below more readable, but this is more a matter of preference, if you will.

```
def flexRemove(S, tup):
    if tup in S:
        S.remove(tup)
    else:
        S.remove(tuple([tup[1], tup[0]]))

S = {(6, 1), (2, 4), (3, 8), (7, 5)}
flexRemove(S, (4, 2))
print(S)
```

You can also write this an one-liner, like below:

```
def flexRemove(S, tup):
    S.remove(tup) if tup in S else S.remove(tuple([tup[1], tup[0]]))
```

Output:

```
{(6, 1), (7, 5), (3, 8)}
```

Comment: Python style is [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp). I would argue that if we are talking about "pythonic" code, exceptions are better than a if statement. You also don't need to search twice in the list (trivial optimisation).

Comment: Since in my situation the probability that exception occur is ~50%, I accepted your arguments that `if..else` approach is best.