# A more idiomatic way to fill a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, idioms

Currently, I'm trying to fill a dictionary in Python but I think what I'm doing is a little bit redundant. Is there a more pythonic way to do the following:

```
if not pattern_file_map.get(which_match):
    pattern_file_map[which_match] = [line]
else:
    pattern_file_map[which_match].append(line)
```

where `pattern_file_map` is a dictionary.

I know that there is a certain idiom to use when checking if there is a key in a dictionary, like 
 [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512557/python-if-key-in-dict-vs-try-except), but I I just want to fill this dictionary with a lists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use

```
pattern_file_map.setdefault(which_match, []).append(line)
```

instead.

Other people might suggest using a `collections.defaultdict(list)` instead, which is another option, but be warned that this might hide errors, since it will silently create all keys you access.

Comment: You can make a `defaultdict` act like a regular dictionary by setting its `default_factory` attribute to `None` (which then makes the code a little uglier).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Good point.  (Note that I'm not opposed to using `defaultdict` at all.)

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding to a maybe existing value:

```
pattern_file_map.setdefault(which_match, []).append(line)
```

If using `dict.get()`:

```
li = pattern_file_map.get(which_match, [])
li.append(line)
pattern_file_map[which_match] = li
```

Of course, both cases are restricted to the case where your dict's values are lists.

Comment: What's the difference between: pattern_file_map.get(which_match, []) and pattern_file_map.setdefault(which_match, [])?

Comment: `.get(key,default)` returns a value or default (without setting) and requires assignment back into the dictionary. `.setdefault(key,default)` is a better choice in this case. I corrected my answer.