# Which approach is better in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, try-catch, production

I am beginner in python and I'm wondering which approach is better assuming I have the following code and which one should be used in production.

```
d = {}
d['a'] = set([0,1,2,0])
d['b'] = set([1,2,1,2])
```

Approach 1:

```
try:
    print(d['c'])
except:
    print(set())
```

Approach 2:

```
try:
   ans = d['c']
except:
    ans = set()
print(ans)
```

Approach 3:

```
if 'c' in d.keys():
    print(d['c'])
else:
    print(set())
```

Approach 4:

```
if 'a' in d.keys():
    ans = d['c']
else:
    ans = set()
print(ans)
```

Comment: For this kind of thing there's `dict.get` (or `defaultdict` if you have lots of these).

Comment: [Don't use bare `except` clauses.](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except)

Comment: Note that is more of a [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) question; there's no problem to be solved here.

Comment: don't use `if 'c' in d.keys():` either,  `if 'c' in d:` does the same thing. What do you want to do with ans?

Comment: Programmers post on the subject: [Python - 'if foo in dict' vs 'try: dict\[foo\]']([Python - 'if foo in dict' vs 'try: dict\[foo\]']([Python - 'if foo in dict' vs 'try: dict\[foo\]'](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/225238))). Then there is [Python: is "Except keyerror" faster than "if key in dict"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20308567) here on SO. In fact, your question is a dupe of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

A `try` and `except` clause works like this.
The code under the `try` statement is executed. As soon as an exception happens in the `try` clause it jumps to the `except` statement. If the error that occurs corresponds to the defined exception that `except` clause is executed.

This is what you would want to do:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = set([0,1,2,0])
d['b'] = set([1,2,1,2])

try:
    print(d['c'])     #if this doesn't exist a KeyError is raised
                     #thus it immediately jumps to the except clause
except KeyError:
    print("No such key in the dictionary")
```

But if you `print(d['a'])` no exception occurs thus the except clause is skipped.