# Time multiple python3 scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timeit

In the future I'll write multiple small scripts in Python 3 which I want to time. One way would be to write every script like this:

```
# functions definitions go here

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import time
  start = time.time()

  # my code

  end = time.time()
  print("This script took {} seconds to execute".format(end - start))
```

But I would have to write this into every single of these scripts. What would be the best way to time my script without including this code every single time (without losing accuracy - I'm aware of `time ./script.py`)?

Comment: what about timeit?

Comment: @SuperStew Would I have to include timeit into every single file?

Comment: I don't think so, but I guess it would depend on your exact setup. Read the docs and see if it'll work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html) vs time module. This is best for comparing one way to do something vs another way to do the same thing.

Here is a *really simple* template:

```
# if f1,f2,f3 are in another module or script, just import...
def f1(s):
    # that function returns something...

def f2(s):
    # etc

def f3(s):
    # etc 

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit    
    for case, x in (('small',1000),('med',10000),('large',1000000)):  
        data=[some data scaled by x]
        print("Case {}, {:,} x, All equal: {}".format(case,x,(f1(data)==f2(data)==f3(data))))
        for f in (f1,f2,f3):
            print("   {:^10s}{:.4f} secs".format(f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(data)", setup="from __main__ import f, data", number=10)))
```

That should get you started. Be more specific of what issue you are having for a more specific answer.

One of my [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308657/298607) has a more compete `timeit` example.

You could also look at [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html) to profile a complete script and identify bottleneck functions. Then use `timeit` to try variants of that bottleneck function.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try a little bit and probably ask a few question later on haha

Answer (score 0):

If you are on unix like environment you can use the shell.

If you are in the same folder as the script:

```
$ time python mymodule.py
real    0m0.307s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.030s
```

If you have the script in a package that is installed (I recommend [editable mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306099/pip-install-editable-vs-python-setup-py-develop/30306403)) you can run from anywhere using the module name

```
$ time python -m mypackage.mymodule
real    0m0.407s
user    0m0.033s
sys     0m0.032s
```

Comment: I do know about time, but I think this isn't accurate (will print 30ms on an empty python file).

Comment: This includes the time to start up the python interpreter.