# Formatting dates within a Python dict

Tags: python

```
 if not all(key in payload for key in payloads[template]):
        raise InvalidPayloadException

    if 'order_date' in payload:
        payload['order_date'] = self._get_formatted_date(payload['order_date'])

    if 'payment_date' in payload:
        payload['payment_date'] = self._get_formatted_date(payload['payment_date'])

    if 'shipped_date' in payload:
        payload['shipped_date'] = self._get_formatted_date(payload['shipped_date'])
```

I have some code that triggers a PDF generation. It accepts a python dict that contains the payload for the PDF.

There are a good few number of dates that need to be displayed in the PDF but not all documents contain all PDFs. I need to format the dates before sending it to the PDF. At the moment my code is a lot of different IF statements to catch all the possible dates and format them in the dict.

Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
for date_key in ('order_date', 'payment_date', 'shipped_date'):
    if date_key in payload:
        payload[date_key] = self._get_formatted_date(payload[date_key])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of the `if` statements.

A common methodology in Python is EAFP (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission) rather than LBYL (Look Before You Leap). Hence you should
prepare a tuple or list of keys you expect to be in the `payload` dict, and use `try-except` in case one of the keys is missing.

```
for key in ('order_date', 'payment_date', 'shipped_date'):
    try:
        payload[key] = self._get_formatted_date(payload[key])
    except KeyError:
        print('{} not in payload dict'.format(key))
```

Comment: Exception handling is not a conditional so checking if something exists is cleaner. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512557/python-if-key-in-dict-vs-try-except) for more explanation

Comment: Yet is less Pythonic, and OP ask for a Pythonic approach. It also depends what is expected to happen more, an existing key or a missing key.

Comment: EAFP is fine when you know exceptions will be, well, exceptional (or when you can have a race condition, which is not the point here). And __NO__, blindly using potentially expensive try/excepts just because someone once said it was "pythonic" when there's a way cheaper solution and no possible race condition is __definitly NOT__ pythonic.

Comment: EAFP is fine, don't know why people have such a big issue with it. This answer is great since it shows another perspective to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could created a tuple of date keys and use a for loop.

```
date_keys = ("order_date", "payment_date", "shipped_date")

for date_key in date_keys:
    if date_key in payload:
        payload[date_key] = self._get_formatted_date(payload[date_key])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a list of all possible dates to format and iterate over them

```
dates = [
    "order_date",
    "payment_date",
    "shipped_date"
]

for d in dates:
    if d in payload:
       payload[d] = self._get_formatted_date(payload[d])
```