# Benefits of ZeroDivisionError in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have two variables x & y, which can be any values. I have to divide x by y. y can be zero. Now I have two approaches

1)

```
if y == 0:      
    continue # or break, supposing there is a loop going on.
```

2)

```
try:
    print 1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print e
finally:
    print "got"
```

My question is, does approach 2 has any benefit over approach 1, if it is, then what is it?

Comment: See [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) vs. [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)

Comment: what about an example with `a/b+c/d+e/f+g/h`. Trivial examples don't necessarily teach good practice.

Answer (score 2):

`try`/`except` might [be slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929887/399367).

In general, the "Pythonic way" is to try to do the thing you want to do and handle an error if it doesn't work ("[Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)"), rather than pre-checking ("[Look Before You Leap](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)"), to give more flexibility in future.

It seems like `y` is usually an integer (instance of `int`) in your code.. but imagine that your requirements evolve, and `y` is an instance of `NewClass` and can now hold a value like `-0.0001`.

In order to maintain compatibility with your application, `NewClass.__eq__()` is written so that `if y == 0` will do an integer comparison (*i.e.* would be `True` in this instance), but `NewClass.__truediv__`uses the float value, so `1 / y` won't return an error.

So, if you use `if` your application will act like `-0.0001 == 0` whereas using `except ZeroDivisionError` will handle the new behaviour correctly.

```
class NewClass(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return int(self) == int(other)
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.value / other

y = NewClass(-0.0001)

if y != 0:
     print 1 / y  # not printed

try:
    print 1 / y  # printed
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

From a performance perspective I would say whether option 2 has any benefit over option 1 depends on how often `y` is 0.

If `y` being 0 is common, then option 2 would be less preferable as it would end up raising the ZeroDivisionError very often , whereas doing the `if y == 0:` or `if y != 0:` check would be less time consuming.

But if y is rarely 0 (that is its an exception case), then option 2 would be more preferable as you would not have the overhead of doing the `if` check and only very rarely would an error be raised.

Example of timing -

```
In [4]: def func2(lst):
   ...:     for i in lst:
   ...:         try:
   ...:             x = 10/i
   ...:         except ZeroDivisionError:
   ...:             pass
   ...:

In [5]:

In [5]: def func1(lst):
   ...:     for i in lst:
   ...:         if i != 0:
   ...:             x = 10/i
   ...:

In [6]: lst1 = [0 for i in range(100)]

In [7]: import random

In [8]: lst2 = [random.randrange(0,5) for i in range(100)]

In [9]: lst3 = [random.randrange(0,15) for i in range(100)]

In [10]: lst2.count(0)
Out[10]: 24

In [11]: lst3.count(0)
Out[11]: 5

In [12]: %timeit func1(lst1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.56 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit func2(lst1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.6 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit func1(lst2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.73 µs per loop

In [15]: %timeit func2(lst2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 18 µs per loop

In [16]: %timeit func1(lst3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.76 µs per loop

In [17]: %timeit func2(lst3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.88 µs per loop
```

Even with only 5% of the numbers being 0 , the `if` loop was still more performant than the `try/except` block.

Basically, Exceptions should be for Exceptional cases.

Comment: The numbers I found suggest that `try`/`except` is slightly faster than `if`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3929887/399367

Comment: (also, "alot" doesn't mean what you think it does…)

Comment: @supervacuo in your example case it only throws error once in the entire loop , even then the `try:except` block was just slightly more performant than the other one. I have included test results, you can see how more performant it would be to use `if` , if the number of 0s in the list being iterated over is even like 10% or so.

Comment: I am not saying `try/except` is bad, its just that it basically depends on the case. Exceptions are for exceptional cases.

Comment: @AnandSKumar within Python, I would disagree - EAFP is preferred in general over LBYL. This concrete numeric case though I would prefer LBYL too, because it IMHO produces code that expresses the algorithm better than catching exceptions.

Comment: I am also talking about this case, where the OP says `y can be zero` . And I never said I prefer LBYL or EAFP , I said it depends on the case, if y being zero is really exceptional case, then EAFP is the way to go. If y being zero is common, then I would prefer `if` loops.

Comment: As Anand says, Exceptions are for exceptional cases, so from the above numbers it makes sense to use `if` if you expect the divisor to be zero 5% or more of the time. Also see the timings in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2522013/4014959).

Comment: Except the original question was about a one-off, not a tight loop where an exception might be raised on many iterations. Re @deets "concrete numeric case", it's not necessarily that clear-cut — see my answer.

Comment: *continue # or break, supposing there is a loop going on.* ?

Comment: @supervacuo Again , I have no idea where you are getting the idea I am only suggesting `if` condition. I am saying it basically depends on how often , even if this is not run in a loop , but still how often y would be `0` . If its a common case that y would be zero, then using `try/except` in that case according to me is plain wrong, not just from the performance perspective, but also from what `Exceptions` stand for, they are to be used in an `Exceptional case` . If the developer already knows that y being zero is common, than that does not constitute an exceptional case.