# Ask a user for 10 integers one at a time and store in list- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```py
score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: "))

while score >= 1 and score <= 300:
    scores.append(score)

    score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: "))

print(scores)
```

I want the user to enter 10 integers one at a time in a loop and store all ten in a list called scores.

Comment: Do you require to the numbers be between 1 and 300?

Comment: use a counter to count the user input count

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, if you do not need the number entered to be restricted within an interval:

```
scores = []
for i in range(10):
   scores.append(int(input())
```

This will repeatedly wait for a user input, and store each value in the `scores` list.
If you want the number to be between 1 and 300, simply place the code you already have in a for loop, or create a counter. You could end up with something like this:

```
scores = []
for i in range(10): 
   score = 0   
   while score >= 1 and score <= 300:
        score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: "))
   scores.append(score)
        
print(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay assuming that all of the input will be valid, you can simply do:

```
scores = [int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: ")) for _ in range(10)]
```

This will raise a `ValueError` if the input isn't convertable to an int, though, and it also won't check for it being in the range.  If you want to re-prompt them on invalid inputs until you have 10 valid inputs, you could make "get a valid score" its own function and then build the list with 10 calls to that:

```
def get_score() -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: "))
            if not (0 <= score <= 300):
                raise ValueError(f"{score} isn't between 0 and 300")
            return score
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}.  Please try again.")

scores = [get_score() for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want for the user to input in different lines then this should work:

```
inputList = []
for i in range(10):
    inputList.append(input("Enter: "))
```

But if you want the user to input all values in same line then use:

```
inputList = map(int, input("Enter: ").split())
```

Comment: you also need to validate if enter value is in (0, 300) range or not

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a different approach than "try this" as it looks like you're a beginner.

To ask a user for an input you can use the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function. It'll give you a string. To convert a string to a number you can utilize [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) or other functions depending on the properties the number should have (decimal numbers, precision, etc).

To repeat a certain action you need to use [a loop](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops). You know `while` as seen in your code. The loop keyword can be nested i.e. you can have a loop within a loop and you can arrange it so that it's checking for the amount of numbers outside of the number limit condition e.g.:

```py
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 10:
    num = int(input("some text"))
    while <your number condition>:
        mylist.append(num)
        ...
    ...
```

or you can utilize `for` loop that will execute the block of code only N-times e.g. with `range(10)`:

```py
mylist = []
for _ in range(10):
    num = int(input("some text"))
    while <your number condition>:
        mylist.append(num)
        ...
    ...
```

With a `while` loop you need to watch out for cases when it might just infinitely loop because the condition is always true - like in your case:

```py
scores = []
score = < a number between 1 and 300, for example 1>

while score >= 1 and score <= 300:  # 1 >= 1 and 1 <= 300  <=> True and True
    scores.append(score)
    score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: "))

print(scores)
```

which will exit in case you enter a number out of the interval but does not guarantee the N-times (10-times) you want. For that to happen you might want to adjust the loop a bit with `break` to stop the execution after 10 values are present:

```py
scores = []
score = < a number between 1 and 300, for example 1>

while score >= 1 and score <= 300:  # 1 >= 1 and 1 <= 300  <=> True and True
    scores.append(score)
    score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300: "))
    if len(scores) >= 10:
        break  # stop the while loop and continue to "print(scores)"

print(scores)
```

However that doesn't handle cases such as inputting `0` or `1000` let's say as once you choose the number out of the interval, it'll stop the `while` loop even if the amount of scores is less than 10.

And then there's the obvious [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) when you simply press `Enter` / `Return` without entering a number or supply a non-numeric value such as `two` which is still a number, but will only crash instead converting to `2` with [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

For the first you'd need to encapsulate the number check in other loop or refactor it into something like this:

```py
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 10:
    num = int(input("some text"))
    if num >= 1 and num <= 300:
        mylist.append(num)
```

which handles even wrong numeric input e.g. `1000` and will ask for another number.

To handle non-numeric input there are at least two ways - you either let it fail or you check the value first:

With fail first you pass the invalid value to `int()` automatically and Python interpreter will generate and raise an [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

```py
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 10:
    try:
        num = int(input("some text"))
    except ValueError as error:
        # do something with the error e.g. print(error)
        # or let it silently skip to the next attempt with "continue"
        continue

    if num >= 1 and num <= 300:
        mylist.append(num)
```

With value validating you can use [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) method which is present on any string instance (which for your case is the return value of [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function):

```py
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 10:
    num = input("some text")
    if not num.isnumeric():
        continue

    if num >= 1 and num <= 300:
        mylist.append(num)
```

And to make it more compact, you can [chain the comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), though with one unnecessary [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) call when the value is correct assuming most of the values are incorrect. In that case `num.isnumeric()` evaluates to `False` first and prevents all [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) calls while if the input is numberic you end up calling [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) **and** 2x [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```py
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 10:
    num = input("some text")
    if num.isnumeric() and 1 <= int(num) <= 300:
        mylist.append(int(num))
```

or the other way around, assuming most of the values are correct you can go for the edge-case of incorrect value with `try` which [would be slower afaik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929935/5994041) but should be faster than always asking whether a string [`isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).

```py
mylist = []
while len(mylist) < 10:
    try:
        num = int(input("some text"))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if 1 <= num <= 300:
        mylist.append(num)
```

Each of the approaches has its own trade off. You can strive for readability, performance, compactness or any other trait and depending on the trait there will be a way to measure it e.g. for performance you might want to use [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) and for readability a linter such as [`pylint`](https://pylint.org).

A minor extra, in case you are creating a CLI tool, you might want to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (interrupt/kill program, will raise [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt)) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (end input, will raise [`EOFError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError)). Both can be handled with `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define the list 'scores'.

`while score >= 1 and score <= 300:` means that if the input value does not between 0 and 300, the loop will be over. Therefore, you may not be able to complete the list of 10 integers. You can check this condition by using `if` instead of `while`.

The while loop need to check if the `scores` list has 10 elements or not.

```
scores = []

while len(scores) < 10:
    score = int(input("Please enter a bowling score between 0 and 300:"))
    if (1 <= score <= 300):
        scores.append(score)
    else: 
        print("Score must be between 0 and 300")
        
print(scores)
```